# what's meaning of this update in Access database?

Tags: sql-server, ms-access

I have a query in an Access database:

```
UPDATE A INNER JOIN (B INNER JOIN C ON B.Control = C.Control) ON A.ClientType = B.Type 
SET C.EstTime = ([A].[AvgTime])*60;
```

What does this mean? I could not figure it out, and can not find the answer after some search.

It seems this is not suported in SQL Server. Or, maybe I missed something?

Thanks

Comment: your query doesn't have a FROM clause so it's kind of not a real thing I'm guesing

Comment: also, sql-server and ms-access are two compltely different things

Comment: a friend asked me this, and obviously, it works in Access database, that's why I ask the question since I do not understand and could not figure it out.

Comment: The reason it doesn't make sense is because it is a SQL fragment from a homework question. ;)  Yet you're saying you ran this successfully in Access? What did it do?

Comment: it is a query being used now, there is no error, but I could not figure out what it does. That's my question.

Comment: Are there tables or queries named `A`, `B`, or `C` in your Access database?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is invalid for a few reasons. One is it is attempting to set a column of `C`, but says `Update A`. The joins first join `B` with `C` and then join that as a single result set to `A`, but I don't think there's really a reason to do that when all joins involved are inner joins. You might see this more commonly if you want to outer join two or more inner joined tables.

Here is an example of an update statement using joined tables: https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2013/04/30/sql-server-update-from-select-statement-using-join-in-update-statement-multiple-tables-in-update-statement/

tl;dr

> ```
> UPDATE Table1
> SET Col2 = t2.Col2,
> Col3 = t2.Col3
> FROM Table1 t1
> INNER JOIN Table2 t2 ON t1.Col1 = t2.Col1
> WHERE t1.Col1 IN (21, 31)
> ```

And here is a question discussing the syntax of combining join types: [SQL Server - Combining OUTER and INNER joins](https://stackoverflow.com/q/473607/263832)

tl;dr

> ```
> select
> *
> from
> a 
> left outer join c
>     inner join b on c.bID = b.ID
> on a.cID = c.ID
> ```

or

> ```
> SELECT * FROM ("purchased_items" p1
>      INNER JOIN "purchase_orders" po1 ON (po1."id" = p1."purchase_order_id")) AS p4
> LEFT OUTER JOIN (purchased_items p2
>       INNER JOIN "purchase_orders" po2 ON (po2."id" = p2."purchase_order_id")) AS p5
> ON (p4.item_variant_id = p5.item_variant_id AND p4.delivery_date < p5.delivery_date) 
> WHERE p5.delivery_date IS NULL AND p4.delivered <> 0
> ```