# Join Tables Where Absolute of Occurrences Equal to Absolute of Single Occurrence

Tags: sql, ms-access

Problem: I am currently trying to join two tables in Access where the absolute value of the total of multiple occurrences of one field in one table is equal to the absolute value of the occurrence in another table.

Am I able to use the Abs function in the WHERE statement? Everything I saw involved the function being used in the SELECT statement. Do I need to create separate queries to get the absolute values? It would also work if I were to check to see if they balance out rather than getting the absolute value.

In one table, a certain value will repeat multiple times while it will only appear once in the other table. How can I get the absolute values of the totals in order to compare it to the single occurrence in the other table? Thanks!

Table 1

| Reference | Amount |
| --- | --- |
| 55555 | $15 |
| 55555 | $20 |

Table 2

| Reference | Amount |
| --- | --- |
| 55555 | -$35 |

If these are equal or if they balance out, they should appear on a query. If these aren't equal but the reference number and a partial amount appears, they should appear on another query.

Comment: Table1 Amount will always be positive and Table2 will always be negative?

Comment: Do you know that all references are always in both tables?

Comment: @Gordon Linoff No, the references will not always be in both tables, but I have another query for those that do not appear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The matching query is relatively simple.  Just aggregate and compare the values:

```
select t2.reference, t2.amount
from (select reference, sum(amount) as amount
      from table2
      group by reference
     ) as t2 inner join
     (select reference, sum(amount) as amount
      from table1
      group by reference
     ) as t1 
     on t1.reference = t2.reference
where t2.amount + t1.amount = 0;
```

However, the non-matches are much trickier -- because presumably a reference could be missing from either table.  And MS Access does not support `full join`.  One method is:

```
select t2.reference, t2.amount, t1.amount
from (select reference, sum(amount) as amount
      from table2
      group by reference
     ) as t2 left join
     (select reference, sum(amount) as amount
      from table1
      group by reference
     ) as t1 
     on t1.reference = t2.reference
where t2.amount + t1.amount <> 0 or t1.amount is null
union all
select t1.reference, null, sum(amount)
from table1 as t1
where not exists (select 1 from table2 as t2 where t2.reference = t1.reference)
group by t1.reference;
```

Comment: It looks like the second algorithm is doing what I need, but I haven't tested it yet. Are there any potential issues I'll run into?

Comment: Should test and find out.

Comment: @June7 . . . This assumes that `amount` is not `NULL` in any of the rows.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff If I need to add more fields, should I create a new query to include those fields and the calculated fields above or will including them in the select statement work? Thanks!

Comment: @BobtheBuilder . . . I don't know.  This answers the question you have asked here.  The data needs to be summarized by *something* which is the reference.  You can summarize other columns without an issue, but you might want to ask a new question.

Comment: I'm wondering if it would be better to do an inner join on the table 1 and then an outer join on the third table created by the second algorithm you wrote. Like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/473607/sql-server-combining-outer-and-inner-joins

Comment: @GordonLinoff When trying to test the second algorithm, I run into the issue of having to input the amounts for both tables as a parameter value.

Answer (score 1):

Aggregate data in Table1 and join to Table2.

Consider:

```
SELECT Table2.*, SumAmt FROM Table2 
INNER JOIN (SELECT Reference, Sum(Amount) AS SumAmt FROM Table1 GROUP BY Reference) AS T 
ON Table2.Reference = T.Reference 
WHERE SumAmt = -Table2.Amount;
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but what should I do in the case that both a sum amount and reference are found, but the sum amounts do not equal zero?

Comment: Build another query with different filter criteria. Isn't that what you stated you wanted? Or don't include filter criteria and pull all records.

Comment: If I want to add more fields, I would add them to the SELECT statement and then use the GROUP BY statement, correct?

Comment: If you add more fields in the aggregate query, data won't be summarized by Reference and Amounts will never agree.

Answer (score 0):

you can use sub-query as follows:

```
select t1.reference from
(select reference, sum(amount) as amount from table1 group by reference) t1
join table2 t2 
  on abs(t1.amount) = abs(t2.amount)
```

Comment: Tested, this syntax fails.

Answer (score 0):

You can list if the amounts match or not, no Abs is needed:

```sql
Select
    Table2.Reference,
    Table2.Amount,
    (T.Total = -Table2.Amount) As T1Match
From
    Table2
Inner Join
    (Select
        Table1.Reference,
        Sum(Table1.Amount) As Total
    From
        Table1
    Group By
        Table1.Reference) As T
    On T.Reference On Table2.Reference
```