# The multi-part identifier could not be bound (join sub query)

Tags: sql, t-sql, join

Possible duplicate, but providing no insight to this case:
[The multi-part identifier could not be bound](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7314134/the-multi-part-identifier-could-not-be-bound)

I have a query of the following form:

```
select l.id, l.foo, r.id, r.foo
from tbl l 
    inner join storyevents r on l.id = r.id
    right join (
        select distinct foo from tbl where id= l.id
    ) tmp on l.foo = tmp.foo
where l.foo = 12345
```

But i get the following error:

```
The multi-part identifier "l.id" could not be bound.
```

in relation to the `right join` sub query.

Bonus points:
This is an attempt to remove duplicate rows from the `inner join` based on a single column. Better way to do this?

Comment: I think some example data may help here

Comment: The error message will also include the line.  I suspect it is where extid = l.id as cannot use it in the ()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this,

```
SELECT l.id, l.foo, r.id, r.foo
FROM   storyevents l 
         INNER JOIN storyevents r 
               ON l.id = r.id
         RIGHT JOIN 
         (
               SELECT distinct extid, foo 
               FROM storyevents
         ) tmp on l.foo = tmp.foo AND
                  tmp.extid = l.id
where l.foo = 12345
```

Comment: Answer as this resolved the error (scope of the ID reference). Still does not cut down result set to match those in tmp though.

Answer (score 0):

Better way to remove duplicate rows?

```
 select distinct l.id, l.foo, r.id, r.foo 
 ....
```

Comment: Unfortunately the combination of id and foo on l and r results in 'unique' combinations of the same rows multiple times. If I could apply distinct to just foo this would be perfect