# how to fix:-org:jooq.exception.DataAccessException and com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException?

Tags: java, sql, database, exception, jooq

Anybody give me any idea how can resolve  exception here

> Console show both Exception:-
>   SEVERE:

```
 (1)   org.jooq.exception.DataAccessException: SQL [select dbo.FolderInfo.FolderRSN, dbo.FolderInfo.InfoCode, dbo.FolderInfo.InfoValue, dbo.FolderInfo.InfoValueCrypt, dbo.FolderInfo.InfoValueNumeric, dbo.FolderInfo.DisplayOrder, dbo.FolderInfo.PrintFlag, dbo.FolderInfo.StampDate, dbo.FolderInfo.StampUser, dbo.FolderInfo.InfoValueDateTime, dbo.FolderInfo.Mandatory, dbo.FolderInfo.ValueRequired, dbo.FolderInfo.InfoValueUpper, dbo.FolderInfo.SecurityCode, dbo.FolderInfo.WebDisplayFlag, dbo.ValidInfo.InfoCode, dbo.ValidInfo.InfoDesc, dbo.ValidInfo.ConversionFlag, dbo.ValidInfo.InfoType, dbo.ValidInfo.InfoGroup, dbo.ValidInfo.DisplayFormat, dbo.ValidInfo.InfoGroupDisplayOrder, dbo.ValidInfo.StatisticFolderInfo, dbo.ValidInfo.StatisticPeopleInfo, dbo.ValidInfo.WebDisplayFlag, dbo.ValidInfo.InfoDesc2, dbo.ValidInfo.StampDate, dbo.ValidInfo.StampUser, dbo.ValidInfo.AccessCode, dbo.ValidInfo.WebHelp, dbo.ValidInfo.Comments, dbo.ValidInfo.PickSelectCode, dbo.ValidInfoGroup.InfoGroup, dbo.ValidInfoGroup.AccessCode, dbo.ValidInfoGroup.StampDate, dbo.ValidInfoGroup.StampUser, dbo.ValidInfoGroup.InfoGroup2, dbo.ValidInfoGroup.Comments, dbo.FolderInfo.FolderRSN, dbo.FolderInfo.InfoCode, dbo.FolderInfo.InfoValue, dbo.FolderInfo.InfoValueCrypt, dbo.FolderInfo.InfoValueNumeric, dbo.FolderInfo.DisplayOrder, dbo.FolderInfo.PrintFlag, dbo.FolderInfo.StampDate, dbo.FolderInfo.StampUser, dbo.FolderInfo.InfoValueDateTime, dbo.FolderInfo.Mandatory, dbo.FolderInfo.ValueRequired, dbo.FolderInfo.InfoValueUpper, dbo.FolderInfo.SecurityCode, dbo.FolderInfo.WebDisplayFlag, dbo.ValidInfoGroup.InfoGroup, dbo.ValidInfoGroup.AccessCode, dbo.ValidInfoGroup.StampDate, dbo.ValidInfoGroup.StampUser, dbo.ValidInfoGroup.InfoGroup2, dbo.ValidInfoGroup.Comments from dbo.FolderInfo, dbo.ValidInfo, dbo.ValidInfoGroup join dbo.FolderInfo on dbo.ValidInfo.InfoCode = dbo.FolderInfo.InfoCode left outer join dbo.ValidInfoGroup on dbo.ValidInfoGroup.InfoGroup = dbo.ValidInfo.InfoGroup where dbo.FolderInfo.FolderRSN = ?]; The multi-part identifier "dbo.ValidInfo.InfoCode" could not be bound.
            at org.jooq.impl.Utils.translate(Utils.java:1121)
            at org.jooq.impl.DefaultExecuteContext.sqlException(DefaultExecuteContext.java:462)
```

(2)

```
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The multi-part identifier "dbo.ValidInfo.InfoCode" could not be bound.
>>  at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDatabaseError(SQLServerException.java:216)
```

> i hava code here before convert jooq

```
            dw.setSelect_SELECT(StringUtils.join(getColumns(), ", "));
        dw.setSelect_FROM("FolderInfo");
        dw.setSelect_FROM("ValidInfo");
        dw.setSelect_FROM("ValidInfoGroup");

        String where = null;
        if (isOracleConnectionCache()) {
            where = "ValidInfo.InfoCode = FolderInfo.InfoCode AND ValidInfoGroup.InfoGroup =+ ValidInfo.InfoGroup AND FolderInfo.FolderRSN = ?";
        } else {
            where = "ValidInfo.InfoCode = FolderInfo.InfoCode AND ValidInfoGroup.InfoGroup =* ValidInfo.InfoGroup AND FolderInfo.FolderRSN = ?";
        }

        dw.setSelect_WHERE(where);
        dw.setSelect_ARG(folderRSN);
```

> But after convert the code into jooq

```
selectQuery.addFrom(FolderInfo.FOLDER_INFO);
        selectQuery.addFrom(ValidInfo.VALID_INFO);
        selectQuery.addFrom(ValidInfoGroup.VALID_INFO_GROUP);
        selectQuery.  addJoin(FolderInfo.FOLDER_INFO, ValidInfo.VALID_INFO.INFO_CODE.eq(FolderInfo.FOLDER_INFO.INFO_CODE));
        selectQuery.addJoin(ValidInfoGroup.VALID_INFO_GROUP,JoinType.LEFT_OUTER_JOIN,
                ValidInfoGroup.VALID_INFO_GROUP.INFO_GROUP.eq(ValidInfo.VALID_INFO.INFO_GROUP));
        selectQuery.addConditions(FolderInfo.FOLDER_INFO.FOLDER_RSN.eq(folderRSN));
```

> In which lines wrong in my jooq code ,how can i make connection through
>   it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exception message is this.

```
The multi-part identifier "dbo.ValidInfo.InfoCode" could not be bound.
```

Googling this message will lead back to Stack Overflow where a [good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7314936/521799) indicates that:

> You are mixing implicit joins with explicit joins. That is allowed, but you need to be aware of how to do that properly.

This is also the case for your query. See more details here:

[The multi-part identifier could not be bound](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7314134/521799)

I personally suggest to never mix implicit joins with explicit joins.

Comment: I Just tested 1-I am connecting with right DB (2) I added JOOQ generated variable declaration. (3)-This Point is not clear to me (4) We have a global connection user/password so other user are able to access same table only i am getting issue

Comment: @SitansuSSwain: I misread the exception message. I thought it said "found", not "bound". Updating my answer...