# Laravel 5.1 Average

Tags: php, sql-server, laravel, eloquent

I have an SQL query which should return the Average cost price from the table.

I have a few joins because I need to pull certain statuses from the order header.

See eloquent query.

```
return $avgsell = DB::table('STK_STOCK')
        ->join('ORD_DETAIL','ORD_DETAIL.OD_ORDER_NUMBER','=','ORD_HEADER.OH_ORDER_NUMBER')
        ->where('ORD_HEADER','ORD_DETAIL.OD_STOCK_CODE','=',$code)->where('ORD_HEADER.OH_PRIORITY','<>',4)->where('ORD_DETAIL.OD_QTYORD','<>','0')
        ->avg('ORD_DETAIL.OD_UNITCST');
```

I get the following error

> SQLSTATE[42000]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL
>   Server]Incorrect syntax near 'ORD_HEADER'. (SQL: select
>   avg([ORD_DETAIL].[OD_UNITCST]) as aggregate from [STK_STOCK] inner
>   join [ORD_DETAIL] on [ORD_DETAIL].[OD_ORDER_NUMBER] =
>   [ORD_HEADER].[OH_ORDER_NUMBER] where 0005-20-02-01 [ORD_HEADER] =
>   ORD_DETAIL.OD_STOCK_CODE [ORD_HEADER].[OH_PRIORITY] <> 4 and
>   [ORD_DETAIL].[OD_QTYORD] <> 0)

Answer (score 1):

In where condition the error coming because you are passing  three params

```
->where('ORD_HEADER','ORD_DETAIL.OD_STOCK_CODE','=',$code)
```

remove ORD_HEADER or ORD_DETAIL.OD_STOCK_CODE

the final code

```
 return $avgsell = DB::table('STK_STOCK')
        ->join('ORD_DETAIL','ORD_DETAIL.OD_ORDER_NUMBER','=','ORD_HEADER.OH_ORDER_NUMBER')
        ->where('ORD_DETAIL.OD_STOCK_CODE','=',$code)->where('ORD_HEADER.OH_PRIORITY','<>',4)->where('ORD_DETAIL.OD_QTYORD','<>','0')
        ->avg('ORD_DETAIL.OD_UNITCST');
```

Comment: Thanks Veerendra - I have amended per your example but I got the following error:          The multi-part identifier "ORD_HEADER.OH_ORDER_NUMBER" could not be bound.

Comment: Are you joining three tables?  i think your query is not correct.paste your models here or check below link [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7314134/the-multi-part-identifier-could-not-be-bound]

Comment: example query:        return $avgsell = DB::table('users')
        ->join('posts','users.id','=','posts.users_id')
        ->where('posts.name','=',$name)->get();