# Multiple InnerJoin

Tags: sql, database

I would like for a multiple table to be Inner joined but somehow, the FROM is not reading. The columns aren't filled with the datas. But they're generating the columns. Is FROM Statement wrong?

```
SELECT Customer.CID, Customer.FName, Customer.LName, Customer.Address, Customer.ContactNo,
   Book.BID as Book_SerialNo, Book.Title, ShoppingCart.Quantity, Order1.Status, Order1.ODate

FROM Customer Inner Join ShoppingCart on Customer.CID = ShoppingCart.CID, 
 Order_Book_Junction Inner Join Book on Order_Book_Junction.BID = Book.BID
 Inner Join Order1 on Order_Book_Junction.OID = Order1.OID
```

Comment: Just putting this out there, this isn't a C# issue, looks like a SQL issue to me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's sql question not C#

You should run it in sql and see the error message or maybe not an error  query doesn't return any row ,Change From statement to (maybe help) :

```
   FROM Customer 
   Inner Join ShoppingCart
          on Customer.CID = ShoppingCart.CID 
   Inner Join Book
          on Order_Book_Junction.BID = Book.BID
   Inner Join Order1
          on Order_Book_Junction.OID = Order1.OID
```

Comment: This is the error message i get when i test in sql
`The multi-part identifier "Order_Book_Junction.OID" could not be bound.`

Comment: So its your main question, and look at here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7314134/the-multi-part-identifier-could-not-be-bound