# Error: The multi-part identifier could not be bound

Tags: sql-server

```
select teamid, 
       a.playerid, 
       dbo.FullName(a.playerid) as fullName, 
       Total_Hits, 
       Total_At_Bats, 
       Totals_At_Bats, 
       Batting_Avg, 
       Team_Batting_Rank, 
       All_Batting_Rank 
FROM batting
```

Error message received:

> Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   The multi-part identifier "a.playerid" could not be bound.

Comment: what is 'a'?Where does it come from?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The multi-part identifier could not be bound](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7314134/the-multi-part-identifier-could-not-be-bound)

Answer (score 0):

Simply remove the `a` alias cause there no `a` alias/table in the `FROM` clause, that's why you get this error message, because SQL Server can't find `playerid` column in a table named/aliased `a`

```
select teamid, 
       playerid, 
       dbo.FullName(playerid) as fullName, 
       Total_Hits, 
       Total_At_Bats, 
       Totals_At_Bats, 
       Batting_Avg, 
       Team_Batting_Rank, 
       All_Batting_Rank 
FROM batting
```

There is no column `a.playerid` there, unless you add an alias to your table as

```
FROM batting a
```