# Insert rows not contained in one table to another

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have two nearly identical tables, but for a difference of about 100 rows (out of 150k). I know how to find all the rows that exist in one table but not the other by using

```
SELECT [Column]
FROM [DB].[dbo].[Table_1] 
WHERE NOT EXISTS 
(SELECT * 
 FROM [DB].[dbo].[Table_1a] 
 WHERE [EDB].[dbo].[Table_1a].[Column] = [DB].[dbo].[Table_1].[Column])
```

But I want to be able to insert the rows missing from `Table_1` into `Table_1a`, but the above code doesn't work in an insert statement:

```
INSERT [DB].[dbo].[Table_1] 
SELECT *
FROM [DB].[dbo].[Table_1a]
WHERE NOT EXISTS 
    (SELECT * 
     FROM [DB].[dbo].[Table_1a] 
     WHERE [DB].[dbo].[Table_1a].[Column] = [DB].[dbo].[Table_1].[Column])
```

As I get the error: The multi-part identifier "DB.dbo.Table_1.Column" could not be bound.

I have looked into that error from [The multi-part identifier could not be bound](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7314134/the-multi-part-identifier-could-not-be-bound) and http://www.sql-server-helper.com/error-messages/msg-4104.aspx but neither of those solve my problem as I am not using `JOIN` or aliases. So, I am not particularly sure what to do.

I am using SQL Server 2017.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get all the rows from `[DB].[dbo].[Table_1a]` that do not exist in `[DB].[dbo].[Table_1a]`, by using left join:

```
INSERT [DB].[dbo].[Table_1] 
  SELECT t1a.*
  FROM [DB].[dbo].[Table_1a] t1a
  LEFT JOIN [DB].[dbo].[Table_1] t1
  ON t1a.[Column] = t1.[Column]
  WHERE t1.[Column] IS NULL
```

Comment: Why does the last line `WHERE t1.[Column] IS NULL` need to be there? What does that do?

Comment: The `LEFT JOIN` will fetch **all** rows from `[DB].[dbo].[Table_1a]` joined with the matching rows from `[DB].[dbo].[Table_1]`. When there is no matching row in `[DB].[dbo].[Table_1]`  (this is what you need) then `t1.[Column]` will be `NULL`. See this for more examples: http://www.sql-join.com/sql-join-types/

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you have two FROM clause references to `[DB].[dbo].[Table_1a]` and you have not aliased them.

So in the WHERE clause of the subquery (which has access to both the inner and outer queries, and therefore to both occurrences of `[DB].[dbo].[Table_1a]`) the optimizer doesn't know which one you mean here:

`WHERE [DB].[dbo].[Table_1a].[Column] = ...`

If you give two different aliases to those table references, and pick one in the WHERE clause, you should be fine:

```
INSERT [DB].[dbo].[Table_1] 
SELECT *
FROM [DB].[dbo].[Table_1a] t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS 
    (SELECT * 
     FROM [DB].[dbo].[Table_1a] t2
     WHERE t2.[Column] = [DB].[dbo].[Table_1].[Column])
```

EDIT:

Another problem is that you are inserting into `Table_1` the records in `Table_1a` WHERE there does not exist a record in `Table_1a` that matches a record in `Table_1`.

This doesn't make much sense.  Probably what you meant to do is insert the `1a` records that do not already exist in `1`.  So probably what you meant is this, which works fine:

```
INSERT INTO Table_1
SELECT * FROM Table_1a t2
WHERE NOT EXISTS(
    SELECT * FROM Table_1 t1
    WHERE t1.Col1=t2.Col1
)
```

Comment: I tried this and I got the same error. Any idea why?

Comment: Ok, yes there is a logical flaw in the query you started with, I will edit my answer.