# Fatal Error due to PDO Exception because of a SQL query with dynamic PHP input

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, database

After almost a day of researching I cannot really see what the error with my code is. I am trying to create a small prototype function that returns the number of rows of query results.

The error I get is: `Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]The multi-part identifier "my@email.com" could not be bound. in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\index.php:59`

Row 59 being `$stmt->execute();`.

I believe the issue comes from my SQL query but I am not 100% sure.

The way the code works is by getting values from a POST input and it checks in a row and column if it contains said value in a schema.

Additionally, I am using MSSQL(not MySQLi) and PHP for the task.

---

This is the main bit where I want the php code to send an SQL query and the check if the result exists.

```
<?php  
    include "connect.php";

    if(isset($_POST['login']))
    {
        $email = $_POST['EMAIL'];
        $password = $_POST['PASSWORD']; 

        $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE EMAIL=$email;"); 
        $stmt->execute();

        $count= $stmt->rowCount();
        echo "Row count: $count \n";
    }
?>
```

Just to mention I have tried all kinds of changes to the SQL query like:

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE EMAIL='".$email."';");
```

and

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE EMAIL=?;");
```

with an array input that had `$email` in it.

**All returned the same identical error.**

---

Here I have the `connect.php`, just in case the issue might come from here.

```
<?php 
        $servername = "localhost";
        $username = "sa";
        $password = ""; 

        try 
        {
            $conn = new PDO("sqlsrv:Server=$servername; Database=db", $username, $password);
            // set the PDO error mode to exception
            $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
            echo "Connected!";
            return $conn;
        }

        catch(PDOException $e)
        {
            echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
        }
?>
```

Comment: @B001ᛦ Oh dear, I apologise.

Comment: `Incorrect syntax near` what exactly?

Comment: Sorry @u_mulder, I accidentally pasted the wrong error log. Now its fixed in the lines above.

Comment: At the time I was experimenting to see if the issue was with the type of input but I do not think it was.

Comment: `$email` is a __string__ value and should be quoted. Or use prepared statements.

Comment: Yes, I said above I tried to add it in as `EMAIL=' " .$email. " '` but it gave me back the same error.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The multi-part identifier could not be bound](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7314134/the-multi-part-identifier-could-not-be-bound)

Comment: It can't give you same error.

Comment: @u_mulder Wow, i was apparently so wrong! I believe that error buffer got bugged or something like that as it kept returning the error I mentioned above. This is the error I get now: `PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]The data types text and varchar are incompatible in the equal to operator. in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\index.php:59`

Comment: `SELECT * FROM users WHERE CONVERT(NVARCHAR, EMAIL)= '".$email."'; ` is the query I am using now.

Comment: All right, now it returns a row value of `-1`. That's not how it supposed to work, is it?

Comment: Is this really how `rowCount();` is supposed to work? Decrement a value instead of incrementing ?

Comment: Probably. See [PHP doc](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php) for full explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically the way I solved the problem was to have the `EMAIL` and `PASSWORD` converted to `VARCHAR`'s:

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT ID, EMAIL, LAST_NAME FROM users WHERE CONVERT(VARCHAR, EMAIL)='my@email.com' AND CONVERT(VARCHAR, PASSWORD)='1234'");
```