# Setting variable in FROM clause causes JOIN error if implicitly declared after table

Tags: mysql, sql

Here is an oddity I cannot explain:

```
FROM (
   SELECT @report_date := 
     IF (DAYOFWEEK(CURDATE()) BETWEEN 3 AND 7, DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY), 
       IF (DAYOFWEEK(CURDATE()) = 1, DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 2 DAY),
         IF (DAYOFWEEK(CURDATE()) = 2, DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 3 DAY), NULL)))
) AS dt
 , t1
LEFT JOIN t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9e0c4/3

Works.

```
FROM t1
 , (
   SELECT @report_date := 
     IF (DAYOFWEEK(CURDATE()) BETWEEN 3 AND 7, DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY), 
       IF (DAYOFWEEK(CURDATE()) = 1, DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 2 DAY),
         IF (DAYOFWEEK(CURDATE()) = 2, DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 3 DAY), NULL)))
) AS dt
LEFT JOIN t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9e0c4/2

Doesn't work, error:

```
Unknown column 't1.id' in 'on clause': ...
```

Why? Note the order of where `t1` is declared in the `FROM` clause.

---

Note, I'm not necessarily looking for alternatives, I would simply like to understand why the order here causes an error on a `JOIN` that I would have thought would occur *following when the `FROM` clause is completed*.

If someone were interested in how I ended up here, see [this broken fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9e0c4/9) and [this working fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9e0c4/8) for a basic example of the real query.

Comment: Note, a very similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/761599/451969

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because you are mixing `ANSI` and `NON-ANSI` join. Instead of using `comma`, replace it with `CROSS JOIN`.

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9e0c4/21)

The issue is precedence, whereas the `JOIN` has higher precedence than the implicit `,`:

> Previously, the comma operator (`,`) and `JOIN` both had the same
>   precedence, so the join expression t1, t2 `JOIN t3` was interpreted as
>   `((t1, t2) JOIN t3)`. Now `JOIN` has higher precedence, so the expression
>   is interpreted as `(t1, (t2 JOIN t3))`. This change affects statements
>   that use an `ON` clause, because that clause can refer only to columns
>   in the operands of the join, and the change in precedence changes
>   interpretation of what those operands are.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html

Use `CROSS JOIN` to replace the implicit `JOIN`:

```
FROM t1
CROSS JOIN (
   SELECT @report_date := 
     IF (DAYOFWEEK(CURDATE()) BETWEEN 3 AND 7, DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY), 
       IF (DAYOFWEEK(CURDATE()) = 1, DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 2 DAY),
         IF (DAYOFWEEK(CURDATE()) = 2, DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 3 DAY), NULL)))
) AS dt
LEFT JOIN t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9e0c4/21

Comment: This solves my underlying problem (thank you for that), but what does the first sentence mean in practice? Why does it work if I flip them so the latter comes second? I just don't see why this would cause an error... Feel free to confuse me with details, if possible.

Comment: `1.` [ANSI vs. non-ANSI SQL JOIN syntax](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1599050/ansi-vs-non-ansi-sql-join-syntax) `2.` It breaks because the scope of the `ON` condition is limited only within the comma. When you flip it up, it does not break because you have not specified any condition on `dt`. It breaks when you define a condition like this one: [Click Here.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9e0c4/30)

Comment: Ok, that makes sense (as well as [Bill Karwin's answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/761599/451969), which I just unearthed). If you can edit that explanation into the answer, I will accept it.

Comment: @JaredFarrish yeah i'm finding that too `:D`

Comment: Well, I suppose I should have found this before posting the question. Visit [the MySQL `JOIN` docs page](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html) and scroll down to the item beginning in *Previously, the comma operator (,)...* In all honestly, there lies the answer. Not sure if I should delete the question or add as an answer (I generally don't like pure manual quotes as answers).

Comment: you can simply delete it if you are not satisfied with the answers `:)`

Comment: If the ANSI folks were looking to put a bullet in the head of `,` syntax, this would be a decent way to do so. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

you can also use this without left join. with separate all tables by comma

-[fiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9e0c4/26)

EDIT:

either use only joins or use only separated comma tables but not mixed.

Comment: I'm not interested in the removing the `JOIN`(`JOIN`s in the real code's case). This doesn't really explain why it breaks, either.

Comment: it breaks because it mixed between sperated tables by comma and using joins