# How can I resolve this SQL query error?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I get this error :

> The multi-part identifier "dbo.Users.Id" could not be bound.

with my query:

```
Select 
    dbo.Users.Name,
    SUM(dbo.IncomeCategories.YearEstimation - dbo.ExpensCategories.YearBudget)
From 
    Users, IncomeCategories
inner join 
    dbo.ExpensCategories on dbo.Users.Id = dbo.ExpensCategories.Id
where 
    Users.Id = 1
```

Can you help me to solve it please?

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 20 years** ago) and its use is discouraged. It's **especially** bad if you *mix the two styles* as you do - have some tables in a comma-separated list and use proper ANSI `INNER JOIN` for another join ....

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the order of your tables; `JOIN` has a higher precedence that a comma, so when the compiler parses the `JOIN` clause it has not yet parsed out the `Users` table reference.  you can fix that by putting the `Users` table directly before the JOIN:

```
Select Users.Name,SUM(IncomeCategories.YearEstimation-ExpensCategories.YearBudget)
From IncomeCategories, Users
inner join ExpensCategories
on
Users.Id=ExpensCategories.Id
where Users.Id=1
```

Other (potential) problems:

- Be consistent in your table referencing.  You use `dbo.` in some places and not others; either use it everywhere (if you *need* to use `dbo.`) or nowhere (if you don't).
- You do not define a relationship to the `IncomeCategories` table, so you will get a cartesian product (which may be what you want, but it's not clear).
- You have a SUM without a GROUP BY, so you will get an error there unless you add `GROUP BY Users.Name`.
- Joining `Users.Id` to `ExpensCategories.Id` seems odd.  I'd expect `ExpensCategories.UserId` or something

Comment: I think SQL Server will forgive the inconsistent naming. [doesnt cause a problem here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d2fa3/3) Problem is probably the precedence of implicit and explicit joins http://stackoverflow.com/a/761599/73226

Comment: @MartinSmith I think you are correct - I will amend my answer.

Comment: @MartinSmith You are correct - changing the order of the tables should fix the problem.