# Why an error of unknown column with left join in my code?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to do the following query:

```
SELECT g1.Name_Gene as "Name_ref"
     , g1.Type_Gene
     , gr.Class_Name
     , g2.Name_Gene as "Name_avr"
     , path.Name_SpeciePa
     , dis.Name_Disease
     , g1.Id_Genes as "Id_ref"
     , g2.Id_Genes as "Id_avr"
     , dis.Id_Diseases
     , path.Id_Pathogens
FROM plants_genes as pg
   , genes_reference as gr
   , genes as g1
LEFT JOIN avirulence_reference as ar ON (g1.Id_Genes=ar.Id_Genes_ref) 
LEFT JOIN genes as g2 ON (ar.Id_Genes_avr=g2.Id_Genes) 
LEFT JOIN reference_diseases as rd ON (gr.Id_Genes=rd.Id_Genes) 
LEFT JOIN pathogens_diseases as pd ON (rd.Id_Diseases=pd.Id_Diseases) 
LEFT JOIN diseases as dis ON (pd.Id_Diseases=dis.Id_Diseases) 
LEFT JOIN pathogens as path ON (pd.Id_Pathogens=path.Id_Pathogens) 
WHERE pg.Id_Plants='196' AND pg.Id_Genes=g1.Id_Genes AND g1.Id_Genes=gr.Id_Genes
```

And I am getting this error:

> ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'gr.Id_Genes' in 'on clause'

I don't understand why I am getting this error, as `genes_reference` is defined as `gr` and the `Id_Genes` is an existing column.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Mixing implicit and explicit JOINs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/761545/mixing-implicit-and-explicit-joins)

Answer (score 2):

It happens because you are mixing implicit and explicit join notations:

```
FROM genes as g1 
JOIN genes_reference as gr on g1.Id_Genes=gr.Id_Genes 
JOIN plants_genes as pg on pg.Id_Genes=g1.Id_Genes
<...>
WHERE pg.Id_Plants='196'
```

Answer (score 0):

you should change you inner joins to this :
FROM plants_genes as pg
join genes_reference as gr on ({common keys })
join genes as g1 on ( {common keys })