# Query not returning NULL values - SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I've been trying for awhile by changing my query around but no LUCK! I have tables:

```
Demographic
( name, gender, nationality, ethnicity etc)
Reference
(ID, Code as varchar, Description varchar)
```

Basically I add all my values in the `reference` table like `nationality, Gender, ethnicity` then I link it to `demographics`, eg. `ID:1 , Code: Gender , Description: Male`

So in `demographics` any `male` will have value `1` ( the `Reference.ID`)

I've written this query:

```
Select Id, fname, Surname
         ,e.Description as Nationality
         ,a.Description as Gender
FROM Demographics d, Reference e, Reference a
WHERE (d.Nationality = e.ID OR d.Nationality IS NULL) AND (d.Gender = a.ID OR 
d.Gender IS NULL)
```

Without the IS NULL parts it works but it excludes all NULL values. But when I add IS NULL it returns **inaccurate** values like **in Gender column I will have ethnicity values**.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What results are you expecting here? *`NULL`*, in SQL Server, is treated as an unknown value. Thus, an expression like `[Column] != 1` will return false, if the value of `[Column]` is *`NULL`*. Also, it's worth noting that `NULL = NULL` would also return false; as an unknown does not equal an unknown in SQL Server. The only way to compare to a *`NULL`* is by using `IS NULL` and `IS NOT NULL`. Without any sample or expected data, however, I have no idea what you are expecting here. [Forum Etiquette: How to post a T-SQL Question](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Best+Practices/61537/).

Comment: Also, things to avoid, **DON'T** use demlimited lists for your table and use implicit joins in the `WHERE` clause. `JOIN` syntax has been around for decades. Use it.

Comment: I am using IS NULL for Gender and Nationality. so when Gender row is null for example as in no values was specified it will not return it it will just return gender/nationality columns with values. whilst i have many users with no gender / nationality specified

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Mixing implicit and explicit JOINs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/761545/mixing-implicit-and-explicit-joins)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is quite the guess here, however, I think you're problem is that you're writing SQL like you're in the 1980's. As I said in my comment, `JOIN` syntax has been around for decades. Stop using delimited lists for your tables and using implicit joins.

Anyway, I *think* what you need is a `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT d.Id, d.fname, d.Surname,
       n.[Description] AS Nationality,
       g.[Description] AS Gender
FROM Demographics d
     LEFT JOIN Reference n ON d.Nationality = n.ID
     LEFT JOIN Reference g ON d.Gender = g.ID;
```

If this isn't correct, then sample and expected results are going to be needed.

Comment: thanks for your answers! I am in uni and we are being taught 'Where' clause rather than Join. So clearly its still around!

Comment: @Warda it's not. it's really not. you won't see anyone with any kind of reputation in SQL ever recommend, or teach, implicit joins. If your tutor is teaching your `WHERE` implicit joins then they, are teaching it wrong. They are awful. I would honestly be concerned if that's the method they think is correct. I would strongly suggest asking them why they aren't covered `JOIN` syntax, which is part of the ANSI syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Switch to non-deprecated join style and everithing will go right way:

```
Select Id, fname, Surname
         ,e.Description as Nationality
         ,a.Description as Gender
FROM Demographics d
LEFT JOIN Reference e 
  ON e.ID = d.Nationality
LEFT JOIN  Reference a
  ON a.ID = d.Gender
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a `LEFT JOIN` here

```
Select Id, fname, Surname
         ,e.Description as Nationality
         ,a.Description as Gender
FROM Demographics d
    LEFT JOIN Reference e ON d.Nationality = e.ID
    LEFT JOIN Reference a ON d.Gender = a.ID
```

Answer (score 0):

Try following query:

```
    Select Id, fname, Surname
             ,e.Description as Nationality
             ,a.Description as Gender
    FROM Demographics d, Reference e, Reference a
    WHERE   (d.Nationality = e.ID OR (e.ID IS NULL AND d.Nationality IS NULL)) 
    AND     (d.Gender = a.ID OR (a.ID IS NULL AND d.Gender IS NULL))
```

I have tweaked your query a little. I think you are on the right path, just missed a little, while comparing with `NULL`.

When you check for one of the operand for nullability (i.e. `IS NULL`) and miss the other one, query give you all on that missing other side.

Check out this Microsoft TechNet article for further learning: [NULL Comparison Search Conditions - TechNet - Microsoft](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191270(v=sql.105).aspx)