# How do i resolve ORA-00904: "CI"."CATALOG_ITEM_ID": invalid identifier Error at Line: 2 Column: 52

Tags: oracle

I need to create a query that will display title, publisher, ISBN, release date, number of pages, and whether it's carried in any library ("Yes" or "No") For each book in the catalog and sort results by title. I can't have any duplicates either.

The query I have is

```
 select distinct ci.title, ci.publisher, ci.RELEASE_DATE, b.ISBN, b.pages  from  
 catalog_item ci, book b
 left join physical_item pi on pi.CATALOG_ITEM_ID = ci.CATALOG_ITEM_ID
 left join branch b on b.branch_id = pi.branch_id
 left join library l on b.library_id=l.library_id
 order by ci.TITLE
 ;
```

I get the following error

ORA-00904: "CI"."CATALOG_ITEM_ID": invalid identifier
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
*Cause:
*Action:
Error at Line: 2 Column: 52

I don't see how it is invalid

My DDL is as follows:

```
 CREATE TABLE CUSTOMER (Customer_ID NUMBER PRIMARY KEY, Customer_Firstname 
 VARCHAR2(30), Customer_Lastname VARCHAR2(30), Customer_Street VARCHAR2(30), 
 Customer_City VARCHAR2(30), Customer_State VARCHAR2(20), Customer_Zip 
 VARCHAR2(10));

CREATE TABLE BRANCH (Branch_ID NUMBER PRIMARY KEY, Branch_Name VARCHAR2(30), 
Branch_Phone VARCHAR2 (30), Branch_Address VARCHAR2(30), LIBRARY_ID NUMBER);

CREATE TABLE PHYSICAL_ITEM (Physical_Item_ID NUMBER PRIMARY KEY, Branch_ID NUMBER, 
Catalog_Item_ID NUMBER, Copy_Number NUMBER, Date_Purchased DATE); 

CREATE TABLE CATALOG_ITEM (Catalog_Item_ID NUMBER PRIMARY KEY, Title VARCHAR2 (30), 
Description VARCHAR2(30), Publisher VARCHAR2 (30), Release_Date DATE, Type 
VARCHAR2(30));

CREATE TABLE DVD (Catalog_Item_ID NUMBER, Length VARCHAR2(30));

CREATE TABLE BOOK (Catalog_Item_ID NUMBER, ISBN VARCHAR2(13), Pages NUMBER);

CREATE TABLE TRANSACTION (Transaction_ID NUMBER PRIMARY KEY, Date_checkout DATE, 
Date_Due DATE, Date_Returned DATE, Library_Card_ID NUMBER, Physical_Item_ID NUMBER);

CREATE TABLE LIBRARY (Library_ID NUMBER PRIMARY KEY, Library_Name VARCHAR2 (30), 
Library_Phone VARCHAR2(30), Library_Address VARCHAR2(30));

CREATE TABLE LIBRARY_CARD (Library_Card_ID NUMBER PRIMARY KEY, Library_ID NUMBER, 
Customer_ID NUMBER, Card_Number VARCHAR2(30), PIN VARCHAR2(8), Date_Expire DATE);

 ALTER TABLE BRANCH ADD CONSTRAINT Library_ID_FK FOREIGN KEY (Library_ID) REFERENCES 
 LIBRARY (Library_ID);

 ALTER TABLE PHYSICAL_ITEM ADD CONSTRAINT Branch_ID_FK FOREIGN KEY (Branch_ID) 
 REFERENCES BRANCH (Branch_ID);

 ALTER TABLE PHYSICAL_ITEM ADD CONSTRAINT Catalog_Item_ID_FK FOREIGN KEY 
 (Catalog_Item_ID) REFERENCES CATALOG_ITEM (Catalog_Item_ID);

 ALTER TABLE TRANSACTION ADD CONSTRAINT Library_Card_ID_FK FOREIGN KEY 
(Library_Card_ID) REFERENCES LIBRARY_CARD (Library_Card_ID);  

ALTER TABLE TRANSACTION ADD CONSTRAINT Physical_Item_ID_FK FOREIGN KEY 
(Physical_Item_ID) REFERENCES PHYSICAL_ITEM (Physical_Item_ID); 

ALTER TABLE LIBRARY_CARD ADD CONSTRAINT Library_ID_FK1 FOREIGN KEY (Library_ID) 
REFERENCES LIBRARY (Library_ID);

ALTER TABLE LIBRARY_CARD ADD CONSTRAINT Customer_ID_FK FOREIGN KEY (Customer_ID) 
REFERENCES CUSTOMER (Customer_ID);

ALTER TABLE DVD ADD CONSTRAINT Catalog_Item_ID_FK1 FOREIGN KEY (Catalog_Item_ID) 
REFERENCES CATALOG_ITEM (Catalog_Item_ID); 

ALTER TABLE BOOK add CONSTRAINT Catalog_Item_ID_FK2 FOREIGN KEY (Catalog_Item_ID) 
REFERENCES CATALOG_ITEM (Catalog_Item_ID);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mixing implicit and explicit JOINs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/761545/mixing-implicit-and-explicit-joins)

Comment: (Obviously,) This is a faq. Before considering posting please always google your error message or many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular strings/names, & read many answers. If you post a question, use one phrasing as title. See [ask] & the voting arrow mouseover texts.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Mixing implicit and explicit JOINs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/761545/mixing-implicit-and-explicit-joins)