# how to rewrite this query to make it work, mysql left join multiple from

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery, left-join

The principal problem is in this question: 
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57531893/how-i-can-fix-this-query-with-subquery-and-alias-in-left-join-mysql).

**The important think is try to solve this:**

THIS IS THE SIMPLE EXAMPLE QUERY PROBLEM

```
CREATE TABLE a ( id int );
CREATE TABLE b ( id int );
CREATE TABLE c ( id int );

SELECT id
, (SELECT MIN(b.id)
   FROM b LEFT JOIN c ON b.id = c.id 
       AND c.id = a.id
   WHERE b.id = a.id
  ) AS something
FROM a
;
The column 'a.id' in on clause is unknown (within LEFT JOIN)
```

Now, trying to solve the problem I wanted to try with this query:

```
select drf2.opcion 
from respuestas r2, opciones o2
left join detalle_respuesta_fija drf2 on o2.id_opcion = drf2.opcion and r2.id_respuesta
where o2.pregunta = 857
and r2.id_respuesta = 190968

 #1054 - La columna 'r2.id_respuesta' en on clause es desconocida
```

I need the query return this (example):

```
+--------
|Result
+--------
| id
| id
| NULL
| id
| NULL
+--------
```

.

Comment: MySQL 's 8.0.14+ added support for a SQL standard 1999+ keyword [LATERAL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/lateral-derived-tables.html) which allows writing corelated joins..  Or better said a deliverd table (a.k.a subqueries) "prefixed" with `LATERAL` can use a alias from the left side in the delivered table meaning  `...  a LATERAL (SELECT.... b.id = a.id)` becomes valid..

Comment: Your "SIMPLE EXAMPLE" shows a bug in MySQL, but doesn't explain what you want, since it doesn't make sence. The condition `c.id = a.id` in the ON clause is redundant, because `a.id` is equal to `b.id` due to the WHERE clause.

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code; example input with desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. That includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.)  PS You have a syntax error. Read the grammar & manual. Show that constituent subexpressions are OK. Make it clear that your question is about *that error* & ask re your overall goal later in a new post.

Comment: Please paraphrase or quote from other pages. Make your post self-contained.

Comment: Comma means CROSS JOIN but with lower precedence than keyword JOINs. So the left join is done first & the left table of the comma is not known there. So don't mix comma with keyword joins. This is a faq. Before considering posting please always google any error message & many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular strings, names & line numbers & with & without 'site:stackoverflow.com' and read many hits & answers. If you post a question, use one phrasing as title. See [ask] & the voting arrow mouseover texts.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mixing implicit and explicit JOINs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/761545/mixing-implicit-and-explicit-joins)

Comment: @PaulSpiegel The code here does not suffer from the bug in the other post. See my comments.

Comment: @RaymondNijland The problem is that comma has lower precedence.

Comment: @philipxy ? why did you "ping" me  ? i assume that your message was meant for somebody else?? But you are right the topicstarter should ideally not be using the old ansi comma join syntax from SQL 89..

Comment: @philipxy I don't understand what you are trying to tell me. The first "example" fails with a valid SQL query - which is clearly a bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use proper, explicit, **standard** `JOIN` syntax.

In your case, that would be:

```
select drf2.opcion 
from respuestas r2 join
     opciones o2
     on r2.id_respuesta = o2.? left join  -- what column is used for the `JOIN`???
     detalle_respuesta_fija drf2
     on o2.id_opcion = drf2.opcion
where o2.pregunta = 857 and r2.id_respuesta = 190968;
```

If there is no `join` key between the first two tables, just use `cross join`:

```
select drf2.opcion 
from respuestas r2 cross join
     opciones o2 left join
     detalle_respuesta_fija drf2
     on o2.id_opcion = drf2.opcion and drf2.respuesta = r2.id_respuesta
where o2.pregunta = 857 and r2.id_respuesta = 190968
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of subquery you should join the a table and group by id

```
 SELECT a.id MIN(b.id)
 FROM b 
 INNER JOIN a ON a.id = b.id 
 LEFT JOIN c ON b.id = c.id 
     AND c.id = a.id
 GROUP BY a.id
```