# My Left outer join doesn't work in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, left-join

I'm learning SQL I need to make a query that gives all the events but I have a particularity. FK id_festival can be null and column nb_tickets_sold in table events can also be null.

I tried to make following query but I have no results

```
CREATE VIEW project.showEvents AS 
SELECT ev.id_event AS "ID",
ev.event_name AS "Name",
ev.price AS "Price",
fe.festival_name AS "Festival",
ev.event_date AS "Date",
ch.concert_hall_name AS "Hall"
FROM project.concerts co,  project.concert_halls ch,
project.events ev LEFT OUTER JOIN project.festivals fe ON ev.id_festival = fe.id_festival
WHERE ev.id_event = co.id_event
AND ev.id_concert_hall = ch.id_concert_hall
ORDER BY ev.event_date;
```

Comment: Explicit `JOIN`s are evaluated before comma separated joins... Switch to modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax everywhere.

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code; example input (as initialization code) with desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. For errors that includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL that includes DBMS & DDL, which includes constraints & indexes & tabular initialization.

Comment: This is a faq. Before considering posting please always google any error message or many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular strings/names & site:stackoverflow.com & tags, & read many answers. If you post a question, use one phrasing as title. See [ask] & the voting arrow mouseover texts.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Mixing implicit and explicit JOINs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/761545/mixing-implicit-and-explicit-joins)

Answer (score 1):

don't mix implict and explict join

```
  CREATE VIEW project.showEvents AS 
  SELECT ev.id_event AS "ID",
  ev.event_name AS "Name",
  ev.price AS "Price",
  fe.festival_name AS "Festival",
  ev.event_date AS "Date",
  ch.concert_hall_name AS "Hall"
  FROM project.concerts co
  INNER JOIN   project.concert_halls ch ON ev.id_concert_hall = ch.id_concert_hall
  INNER project.events ev  ON ev.id_event = co.id_event
  LEFT OUTER JOIN project.festivals fe ON ev.id_festival = fe.id_festival
  ORDER BY ev.event_date;
```

Comment: I changed it but I have always none results    CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW project.showEvents AS 
SELECT ev.id_event AS "ID",
ev.event_name AS "Name",
ev.price AS "Price",
fe.festival_name AS "Festival",
ev.event_date AS "Date",
ch.concert_hall_name AS "Hall"
FROM project.concert_halls ch
INNER JOIN project.events ev ON ch.id_concert_hall = ev.id_concert_hall
INNER JOIN project.concerts co ON ev.id_event = co.id_event
LEFT OUTER JOIN project.festivals fe ON ev.id_festival = fe.id_festival
ORDER BY ev.event_date;

Comment: Go step by step.  One of your join columns could be wrong or you data may not be what you think it is.  Start with `select * from project.concerts` then add `join project.concert_halls ch ON ...` and so on to see which step causes your loss of results.