# Unknown column in on clause error when joining four tables

Tags: mysql, sql, join, left-join

I want to join four tables, I wrote in many possible ways but I get an error of unknown column and I don't get what's wrong.

This is what I write:

```
SELECT
  kursai.pavadinimas,
  destytojai.vardas AS d_vardas,
  destytojai.pavarde AS d_pav,
  vartotojai.vardas AS v_vardas,
  vartotojai.pavarde AS v_pav
FROM
  kursai,
  (
    vartotojai,
    (
      destytojai
    LEFT JOIN
      pasirinkti_kursai AS p1 ON destytojai.vardas = p1.destytojas_id
    LEFT JOIN
      pasirinkti_kursai AS p2 ON destytojai.pavarde = p2.destytojas_id
    )
  LEFT JOIN
    pasirinkti_kursai AS p3 ON vartotojai.vardas = p3.vartotojas_id
  LEFT JOIN
    pasirinkti_kursai AS p4 ON vartotojai.pavarde = p4.vartotojas_id
  )
LEFT JOIN
  pasirinkti_kursai AS p0 ON kursai.pavadinimas = p0.kursas_id
```

Can you please tell me how should I write the code? This is my first time writing SQL code and I don't know what to do anymore :(

Update:

This is how theses other tables should look like:

```
CREATE TABLE `vartotojai` 
  `elpastas` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `slaptazodis` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `vardas` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `pavarde` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `gimimo_data` date NOT NULL,
  `id` int(5) NOT NULL

CREATE TABLE `destytojai`
  `id` int(5) NOT NULL,
  `vardas` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `pavarde` varchar(30) NOT NULL

CREATE TABLE `kursai` (
  `id` int(5) NOT NULL,
  `pavadinimas` varchar(3) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL,
  `aprasas` text CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL,
  `laikas` date NOT NULL,
  `kaina_teor` decimal(5,2) NOT NULL,
  `kaina_prak` decimal(5,2) NOT NULL,
  `kaina_abu` decimal(6,2) NOT NULL,
  `vietu_sk` int(3) NOT NULL,
  `teor_val` int(3) NOT NULL,
  `prakt_val` int(3) NOT NULL,
  `foto_url` varchar(1000) COLLATE utf16_lithuanian_ci NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf16 COLLATE=utf16_lithuanian_ci;

CREATE TABLE `pasirinkti_kursai` (
  `kursas_id` int(5) NOT NULL,
  `destytojas_id` int(5) NOT NULL,
  `vartotojas_id` int(5) NOT NULL,
  `id` int(5) NOT NULL,
  `kaina` decimal(7,0) NOT NULL,
  `patvirtinta` tinyint(1) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Comment: If you want to join three tables, why does the query have five `left join`s?  Normally two would suffice.

Comment: As I mentioned, this is my frist time writing SQL code so I don't know exactly what to use

Comment: @GordonLinoff can you maybe show how to write this? Because I tried using less 'Left joins' and I got another error

Comment: @AliG.: please show us sample data from the three tables, along with your expected results, as tabular text, so someone can provide a solution.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Mixing implicit and explicit JOINs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/761545/mixing-implicit-and-explicit-joins)

Comment: Comma means CROSS JOIN but with lower precedence than keyword JOINs. So the left join is done first & the left table of the comma is not known there. So don't mix comma with keyword joins. This is a faq. Before considering posting please always google any error message or many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular strings/names & site:stackoverflow.com & tags, & read many answers. If you post a question, use one phrasing as title. See [ask] & the voting arrow mouseover texts.

Comment: The first thing I do is always search in google, but when I don't find an answer then I write here :)

Comment: I gave you my generic faq comment. This is a very hard question for people to find. So I don't fault people who don't find a duplicate. On the other hand, absolute basics of debugging (also [mre]) say to find `select * from x, z`--OK & `select * from y left join z on 1=1`--OK but `select * from x, y left join z on 1=1`--not OK. And what is the name of the duplicate link I gave? Plus one should try putting each join in a subselect to confirm one's expectations & one would find they are wrong. Plus one should read the manual re functionality one is using & that's first comma--and its precedence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Neither of the solutions worked with LEFT JOIN or other joins (with the solution that nbk gave, I got NULL for result), so I wrote it without any JOINS like this:

```
SELECT
  kursai.pavadinimas,
  destytojai.vardas,
  destytojai.pavarde,
  vartotojai.vardas,
  vartotojai.pavarde
FROM
  `pasirinkti_kursai`,
  kursai,
  destytojai,
  vartotojai
WHERE
  pasirinkti_kursai.kursas_id = kursai.id AND pasirinkti_kursai.destytojas_id = destytojai.id AND pasirinkti_kursai.vartotojas_id = vartotojai.id
```

Comment: These are old style joins. You should use the new syntax and not this.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for something like This.

**Be aware** i used left joins,because i don't know nothing about your data.

You should try also inner joins instead of Left ones and see if all the data you want are still there.

And an advice use for tables **aliases**, as you see it is less typing

```
SELECT
  k.pavadinimas,
  d.vardas AS d_vardas,
  d.pavarde AS d_pav,
  v.vardas AS v_vardas,
  v.pavarde AS v_pav
  FROM 
    kursai k
    LEFT JOIN pasirinkti_kursai pk ON k.id = pk.kursas_id
    LEFT JOIN destytojai d ON d.id  = pk.destytojas_id
    LEFT join  vartotojai v ON v.id = pk.vartotojas_id
```