# Multipart identifier column not bound in SQL

Tags: sql-server, join, multipart

Please can you help. I am trying to do something as below:

```
Select tb4.columnName As test1,
   tb2.columnName As test2,
   tb4.columnName As test3 
from [dbname].Table2 tb2, Table1  tb1 
JOIN Table3 tb3 ON tb3.ColumnName = tb1.columnName 
JOIN Table4 tb4 ON tb4.ColumnName = tb3.columnName
JOIN [dbname].Table5 tb5 ON tb5.ColumnName = **tb2.ColumnName**
```

I am getting:

> multipart identifier not bound error at ‘tb2.ColumnName’

Comment: You have nothing joined to `Table2`. Remove the comma between `tb2` and `Table1` and use the `JOIN` statement.

Comment: Sorry didn’t get it Why I have to remove comma? These are two separate tables I did join here JOIN [dbname].Table5 tb5 ON tb5.ColumnName = **tb2.ColumnName**

Comment: I understand that. You are combining old style joins and the `JOIN` statement. Therefore, you are getting the error. Old style joins usually have the condition statements in the `Where` clause.

Comment: Please do you have any example

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Mixing implicit and explicit JOINs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/761545/mixing-implicit-and-explicit-joins)

Comment: Comma means cross join but with lower precedence than keyword JOINs. So the JOIN ON is done first & the left table of the comma is not known there. So don't mix comma with keyword joins. PS If you composed & gave the obligatory [mre] chopping down your code to a miniumum but leaving the problem then it would be select * of a comma & inner join & your question would be a faq.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mix implicit joins (with commas in the `from` clause) and explicit joins (with the `join ... on` syntax). They have different prescendence, so at the time when the last join condition is evaluated, the database does not know about `tb2` yet.

Matter of fact, always use explicit joins: they have been the standard for decades now. Your existing query is seemingly missing a join condition between `tb2`  and `tb1`, but the logic you want should be:

```
select 
    tb4.columnName As test1,
    tb2.columnName As test2,
    tb4.columnName As test3 
from Table2 tb2
inner join Table1 tb1 on ??  -- join condition here
inner join Table3 tb3 on tb3.ColumnName = tb1.columnName 
inner join Table4 tb4 on tb4.ColumnName = tb3.columnName
inner join Table5 tb5 on tb5.ColumnName = tb2.ColumnName
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I was missing a join condition after adding all sorted!! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for. And, you have `tb4.columnName` twice in the select statement.

```
Select tb4.columnName As test1,
   tb2.columnName As test2,
   tb4.columnName As test3 
from [dbname].Table2 tb2
JOIN [dbname].Table5 tb5 ON tb5.ColumnName = tb2.ColumnName
JOIN Table1  tb1 ON tb2.ColumnName = tb1.ColumnName
JOIN Table3 tb3 ON tb3.ColumnName = tb1.columnName 
JOIN Table4 tb4 ON tb4.ColumnName = tb3.columnName
```

Comment: Thank you, that’s really helpful.