# SQL Query: Join (or select) 2 columns from 1 table with 1 column from another table for a view without extra join columns

Tags: sql, join, select, view

This is my very first Stackoverflow post, so I apologize if I am not formatting my question correctly. I'm pounding my head against the wall with what I'm sure is a simple problem. I have a table with a bunch of event information, about 10 columns as so:

Table: event_info

```
date        location_id   lead_user_id   colead_user_id   attendees   start   end   <and a few more...>
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2020-10-10       1           3             1                  26       2100    2200     .
2020-10-11       3           2             4                  18       0600    0700
2020-10-12       2           5             6                  6        0800    0900
```

And another table with user information:

Table: users

```
user_id      user_name     display_name     email     phone     city
----------------------------------------------------------------------
1            Joe S           goofball        ...
2            John T          schmoofball     ...
3            Jack U          aloofball       ...
4            Jim V           poofball        ...
5            Joy W           tootball        ... 
6            George A        boring          ...
```

I want to create a view that has only a subset of the information, not full table joins. The event table `lead_user_id` and `colead_user_id` columns both refer to the `user_id` column in the `users` table.

I want to create a view like this:

```
date         Location      Lead Name      CoLead Name     attendees
---------------------------------------------------------------------
2020-10-10      1           Jack U          Joe S           26
2020-10-11      3           John T          Jim V           18
2020-10-12      2           Joy W           George A        6
```

I have tried the following and several iterations like it to no avail...

```
SELECT 
    E.date, E.location, 
    U1.display_name AS Lead Name, 
    U2.display_name AS CoLead Name. 
    E.attendees
FROM
    users U1, event_info E
INNER JOIN 
    event_info E ON U1.user_id = E.lead_user_id
INNER JOIN 
    users U2 ON U2.user_id = E.colead_user_id
```

And I get the dreaded

> You have an error in your SQL Syntax

message. I'm not surprised, as I've really only ever used joins on single columns or nested select statements... this two columns pointing to one is throwing me for a loop. Help!

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code, including smallest representative example input as code; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. Give the least code you can that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL that includes DBMS & DDL (including constraints & indexes) & input as code in table format. [ask] Pause work on the overall goal, chop code to the 1st expression not giving what you expect & say what you expect & why.

Comment: PS You have a syntax error. Read the grammar & manual. Show that constituent subexpressions are OK. When pinned down this will be is a faq. Please before considering posting read your textbook and/or manual & google any error message or many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular strings/names & site:stackoverflow.com & tags; read many answers. Reflect your research. See [ask] & the voting arrow mouseover texts. If you post a question, use one phrasing as title.

Comment: You are using the same alias twice, e.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mixing implicit and explicit JOINs](https://stackoverflow.com/q/761545/3404097) Comma means cross join but with lower precedence than keyword JOINs. So the JOIN ON is done first & the left table of the comma is not known there. So don't mix comma with keyword joins. (Had you chopped down your code you would have got select * from u1 , ea join eb on c. Now look at the duplicate's title.)

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 25 years** ago) and its use is discouraged. And **mixing** the two styles - having two tables in a comma-separated `FROM`, while two more proper `JOIN` s - is **REALLY** a horribly bad practice!

Comment: Thanks for the great feedback, all. I appreciate the candid criticism of my question and will be better with future posts. I'm really trying to learn, so appreciate those of you with actual helpful feedback and assistance. Telling someone to "go study" isn't exactly helpful. I am well aware of my amateur skillset here. The best way to learn some things is through a combination of hands on trying and study. Thanks again!

Comment: What we have told you is fundamental, helpful & relevant. It is not unhelpful for us to tell people to research because posts do not reflect effective research. PS See [How do comment @replies work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work) to learn to use @x to notify one non-sole non-poster commenter (or other user) x re a comment. (Posters & followers aways get notified.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

correct query for this matter

```
SELECT 
    E.date, E.location, 
    U1.display_name AS Lead Name, 
    (select display_name from users  where user_id=E.colead_user_id) AS CoLead Name, 
    E.attendees
FROM
    event_info E
INNER JOIN 
     users U1 ON U1.user_id = E.lead_user_id
```

Comment: Thank you @Iman. I greatly over-simplified my example question above, but your response gives me exactly what I need to figure it out.

Comment: Your wellcom, please click on true answer icon answer