# Mapping three tables

Tags: mysql, relational-database

I need the number of times team Mercedes achieved position 1.
The NULL values are auto incremented values.

The query which I attempted to write to get the result is:

```
SELECT team.teamName,
       SUM (raceDriver.points) as total_points
  FROM raceDriver,
       team
    LEFT JOIN driver ON driver.driverID = raceDriver.driverID
    LEFT JOIN driver AS drivera ON driver.teamID = team.teamID
  GROUP BY team.teamName
  ORDER BY total_points DESC;
```

Sample schema & data:

```
CREATE TABLE team (
    teamID INT UNSIGNED PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    teamName VARCHAR(256)
);

CREATE TABLE driver (
    driverID INT UNSIGNED PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    firstName VARCHAR(128) NOT NULL,
    lastName VARCHAR(128) NOT NULL,
    teamID INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (teamID) REFERENCES team (teamID)
);

CREATE TABLE qualifierDriver (
    qualifierDriverID INT UNSIGNED PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    positions INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    driverID INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    qualifierRaceID  INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (driverID) REFERENCES driver (driverID)
);


Insert INTO team (teamID, teamName)
values (NULL, 'Mercedes'),
       (NULL, 'RedBull');

Insert INTO driver (driverID, firstName,lastName,teamID)
values (44, 'Lewis','Hamilton',1),
       (77, 'Valtteri', 'Bottas',1),
       (33, 'Max', 'Verstappen', 2),
       (11, 'Sergio', 'Perez',2);

Insert INTO qualifierDriver (qualifierDriverID, positions, driverID, qualifierRaceID)
VALUES  (NULL, 1,33,1),
        (NULL, 2, 44,1),
        (NULL, 3, 77,1),
        (NULL, 11,11,1),
           
        (NULL, 1,44,2),
        (NULL, 2, 11,2),
        (NULL, 3, 33,2),
        (NULL, 8,77,2),
           
        (NULL, 1,77,3),
        (NULL, 2,44,3),
        (NULL, 3,33,3),
        (NULL, 4,11,3);
```

Comment: The join manual page has a warning about mixing comma and explicit joins

Comment: Why are you joining with `driver` twice? You never use `drivera` anywhere.

Comment: You never check for position 1 anywhere.

Comment: Thanks for including sample data as DML (so few do). To make an SQL sample complete, it should include table definitions as [DDL](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_definition_language). I added what appeared to be suitable definitions based on the DML statements; please make any necessary corrections, such as a definition & data for `raceDriver`.

Comment: Is `raceDriver` the same as `qualifierDriver`? If so, which should be used?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Mixing implicit and explicit JOINs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/761545/mixing-implicit-and-explicit-joins)

Answer (score 0):

The question says to get the count, not the total points, so just use `SELECT COUNT(*)`.

Then just join all 3 tables and restrict to the team name you want. You don't need `GROUP BY` if you're just getting results for team Mercedes.

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM qualifierDriver AS qd
JOIN driver AS d ON qd.driverID = d.driverID
JOIN team AS t ON t.teamID = d.teamID
WHERE t.teamName = 'Mercedes'
AND qd.positions = 1
```

There's no reason to use `LEFT JOIN` here, because you'll get a count of `0` if there are no matches with `INNER JOIN`.

Comment: I missed out the condition with position 1 and joining driver twice. Your suggestion worked.Thanks.