# Oracle DB SQL SELECT FROM a, b INNER JOIN c : is that possible?

Tags: sql, oracle, inner-join, oracle19c

I had a SQL

```sql
SELECT dtl.ACCT_YM              AS ACCT_YM,
       src.SRC_NAME             AS SRC_NAME,
       ptnr.PTNR_NAME           AS PTNR_NAME,
       info.PTNR_COMPANY_ID     AS PTNR_COMPANY_ID
FROM MPTNR_DTL dtl,
     (SELECT SRC_ID ,SRC_NAME FROM SOURCE_VIEW WHERE DELETED = '0') src,
     (SELECT PTNR_ID ,PTNR_NAME FROM PARTNER_MV WHERE DELETED = '0') ptnr
INNER JOIN PTNR_INFO info ON (info.DELETED = '0' AND info.ACCT_YM = dtl.ACCT_YM)
WHERE dtl.ACCT_YM = '202204'
  AND dtl.DELETED = '0'
  AND ROWNUM <= 10
ORDER BY dtl.SRC_ID;
```

I tried it on the SQLplus but it was a wrong SQL.
The error was: dtl.ACCT_YM can not be recognized.

The basic sentence is

SELET a,b,c
FROM table_1, (sub select) table_2, (sub select) table_3
INNER JOIN table_3
WHERE XXXX

How can I fix it? Thank you!

Comment: Explicit JOINs are evaluated before implicit, comma separated ones. This means your ON clause has no access to dtl columns.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Mixing implicit and explicit JOINs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/761545/mixing-implicit-and-explicit-joins)

Answer (score 0):

The way I see it, it should be a join of 3 different tables:

```
  SELECT dtl.acct_ym, src.src_name, ptnr.ptrn_name
    FROM mptnr_dtl dtl
         JOIN source_view src ON src.src_id = dtl.src_id
         JOIN partner_mv ptnr ON ptnr.some_id = dtl.some_id      --> which ID?
         JOIN ptnr_info info ON info.acct_ym = dtl.acct_ym
   WHERE     src.deleted = '0'
         AND ptnr.deleted = '0'
         AND info.deleted = '0'
         AND dtl.deleted = '0'
         AND dtl.acct_ym = '202204'
         AND ROWNUM <= 10
ORDER BY dtl.src_id
```

I don't know join conditions so I *guessed* column names (as you didn't post table descriptions nor relations among them).

Answer (score 0):

If you really wanted a mix of legacy comma and ANSI joins (please don't) then you need to have the ANSI joins before the comma joins:

```sql
SELECT dtl.ACCT_YM              AS ACCT_YM,
       src.SRC_NAME             AS SRC_NAME,
       ptnr.PTNR_NAME           AS PTNR_NAME,
       info.PTNR_COMPANY_ID     AS PTNR_COMPANY_ID
FROM   MPTNR_DTL dtl
       INNER JOIN PTNR_INFO info ON (info.DELETED = '0' AND info.ACCT_YM = dtl.ACCT_YM),
       (SELECT SRC_ID ,SRC_NAME FROM SOURCE_VIEW WHERE DELETED = '0') src,
       (SELECT PTNR_ID ,PTNR_NAME FROM PARTNER_MV WHERE DELETED = '0') ptnr
WHERE  dtl.ACCT_YM = '202204'
  AND  dtl.DELETED = '0'
  AND  ROWNUM <= 10
ORDER BY dtl.SRC_ID;
```

However, that is bad practice and it would be better to stick to a single join syntax throughout.

You have an additional issue that the `ROWNUM` is generated as the rows are read and the `WHERE` filter is applied before the `ORDER BY` clause so you will get the first 10 random rows and then order them.

---

From Oracle 12, the legacy comma joins and the row limiting filter can be translated to:

```sql
SELECT dtl.ACCT_YM              AS ACCT_YM,
       src.SRC_NAME             AS SRC_NAME,
       ptnr.PTNR_NAME           AS PTNR_NAME,
       info.PTNR_COMPANY_ID     AS PTNR_COMPANY_ID
FROM   MPTNR_DTL dtl
       CROSS JOIN (SELECT SRC_ID ,SRC_NAME FROM SOURCE_VIEW WHERE DELETED = '0') src
       CROSS JOIN (SELECT PTNR_ID ,PTNR_NAME FROM PARTNER_MV WHERE DELETED = '0') ptnr
       INNER JOIN PTNR_INFO info ON (info.DELETED = '0' AND info.ACCT_YM = dtl.ACCT_YM)
WHERE  dtl.ACCT_YM = '202204'
AND    dtl.DELETED = '0'
ORDER BY dtl.SRC_ID
FETCH FIRST 10 ROWS ONLY;
```

Or, more simply:

```sql
SELECT dtl.ACCT_YM              AS ACCT_YM,
       src.SRC_NAME             AS SRC_NAME,
       ptnr.PTNR_NAME           AS PTNR_NAME,
       info.PTNR_COMPANY_ID     AS PTNR_COMPANY_ID
FROM   MPTNR_DTL dtl
       CROSS JOIN SOURCE_VIEW src
       CROSS JOIN PARTNER_MV ptnr
       INNER JOIN PTNR_INFO info ON (info.DELETED = '0' AND info.ACCT_YM = dtl.ACCT_YM)
WHERE  dtl.ACCT_YM = '202204'
AND    dtl.DELETED = '0'
AND    src.DELETED = '0'
AND    ptnr.DELETED = '0'
ORDER BY dtl.SRC_ID
FETCH FIRST 10 ROWS ONLY;
```

In Oracle 11 and earlier, you would want to `ORDER` first and then filter by `ROWNUM` (instead of filtering on the first 10 random rows and then ordering those random rows):

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   (
  SELECT dtl.ACCT_YM              AS ACCT_YM,
         src.SRC_NAME             AS SRC_NAME,
         ptnr.PTNR_NAME           AS PTNR_NAME,
         info.PTNR_COMPANY_ID     AS PTNR_COMPANY_ID
  FROM   MPTNR_DTL dtl
         CROSS JOIN (SELECT SRC_ID ,SRC_NAME FROM SOURCE_VIEW WHERE DELETED = '0') src
         CROSS JOIN (SELECT PTNR_ID ,PTNR_NAME FROM PARTNER_MV WHERE DELETED = '0') ptnr
         INNER JOIN PTNR_INFO info ON (info.DELETED = '0' AND info.ACCT_YM = dtl.ACCT_YM)
  WHERE  dtl.ACCT_YM = '202204'
  AND    dtl.DELETED = '0'
  ORDER BY dtl.SRC_ID
)
WHERE  ROWNUM <= 10;
```

or:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   (
  SELECT dtl.ACCT_YM              AS ACCT_YM,
         src.SRC_NAME             AS SRC_NAME,
         ptnr.PTNR_NAME           AS PTNR_NAME,
         info.PTNR_COMPANY_ID     AS PTNR_COMPANY_ID
  FROM   MPTNR_DTL dtl
         CROSS JOIN SOURCE_VIEW src
         CROSS JOIN PARTNER_MV ptnr
         INNER JOIN PTNR_INFO info ON (info.DELETED = '0' AND info.ACCT_YM = dtl.ACCT_YM)
  WHERE  dtl.ACCT_YM = '202204'
  AND    dtl.DELETED = '0'
  AND    src.DELETED = '0'
  AND    ptnr.DELETED = '0'
  ORDER BY dtl.SRC_ID
)
WHERE  ROWNUM <= 10;
```

---

If you want, you can change the `CROSS JOIN`s to `INNER JOIN` but then you would need to specify a join condition (which is something your existing query does not have).