# Not unique table/alias in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, join, database-design, match

I tried to create a new table that has columns from 2 tables `province` and `district_ward`. Both tables have a column `NAME`, but different values; both tables have a column `PROVINCE_ID` (same value) and this is the column I tried to match.

Expected output is

```
PROVINCE_ID / NAME / NAME
```

Find all `NAME` from `district_ward` that match NAME = "Vung Tau" in province, through `PROVINCE_ID` column.

This is my query, however it throws an error

> 1066: 'not unique table/alias'

```
USE db1;

SELECT province.PROVINCE_ID, province.NAME, district_ward.NAME
FROM province as p, district_ward as d
INNER JOIN d ON p.PROVINCE_ID=d.PROVINCE_ID and p.NAME = "Vũng Tàu"
GROUP BY p.PROVINCE_ID
```

Comment: You have 2 tables & you called them both 'd'. PS [Mixing implicit and explicit JOINs](https://stackoverflow.com/q/761545/3404097 PS Those are both faqs. [mre] [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/3404097) [ask] [Help]

Comment: `...FROM province as p INNER JOIN district_ward as d ON ...`.

Comment: BTW, your GROUP BY is invalid. What are you trying to do? A [mcve] is a great start when asking for SQL assistance.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**30 years!!** ago) and its use is discouraged. And **mixing** both this old style, and then an `INNER JOIN` on top of that, is really totally useless and will cause endless grief and heartaches - stop doing that - NOW.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try this one:

```
USE db1;

SELECT province.PROVINCE_ID, province.NAME, district_ward.NAME

FROM province as p

INNER JOIN district_ward as d USING (PROVINCE_ID)

WHERE p.NAME = "Vũng Tàu"

GROUP BY p.PROVINCE_ID;
```

Comment: I'd expect an error here. `USING (PROVINCE_ID)` means you can't access province.PROVINCE_ID anymore.

Comment: Nice try, but `d` is the problem, not `province_id`.

Answer (score 0):

Do not use "comma JOIN"

```
FROM  province as p, district_ward as d
INNER JOIN  d  ON ...
```

Instead, do

```
FROM  province as p
INNER JOIN district_ward as d  ON ...
```

(Optionally use `USING` instead of `ON` -- But that's not where the problem is.)