# What does a SELECT query using a LEFT JOIN followed by a comma separated table list mean?

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, left-join

I came across this SQL Server SELECT query and I'm not understanding the LEFT JOIN is uses.

```
SELECT *
FROM project p
LEFT OUTER JOIN last_update lu ON lu.parent_table = 'project' AND lu.parent_id = p.record_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN project_final_report pfr ON pfr.project_id = p.record_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN logininfo logr ON logr.login_id = p.project_review_by
LEFT OUTER JOIN logininfo logfr ON logfr.login_id = pfr.last_updated_by
, community c, lookupvalue lv, lookupvalue d, lookupvalue r, lookupvalue su
, lookupvalue a, lookupvalue pc, lookupvalue pm, area_settings
WHERE p.record_id = 12345
AND p.data_system_type = 'P'
AND p.community_id = c.record_id
AND c.epa_region_id = lv.record_id
AND d.record_id = p.district_id
AND r.record_id = p.res_id
AND su.record_id = p.servunit_id
AND a.record_id = p.area_id
AND pc.record_id = p.project_category_id
AND pm.record_id = p.procurement_method_id
AND area_settings.area_id = p.area_id
```

You will notice the last LEFT JOIN is followed by a list of tables separated by commas.
I'm familiar with LEFT JOINS, INNER JOINS and older school comma separated tables with WHERE clauses that turn them into INNER JOINS. But this mixing of LEFT JOIN with CS tables is new to me.

Can you explain how it equates to just LEFT AND INNER JOINS?

Comment: That is the old outdate syntax for a `join`, where the `ON` clause is in the `WHERE` clause

Comment: It's just mixing the two styles you are already familiar with...

Comment: [Bad Habits to Kick : Using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Mixing implicit and explicit JOINs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/761545/mixing-implicit-and-explicit-joins)

Comment: Please before considering posting: Pin down code issues via [mre]. Read manuals/references & google error messages & many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular names/strings/numbers, 'site:stackoverflow.com' & tags; read many answers. SO/SE search is poor & literal & unusual, read the help. Google re googling/searching, including Q&A at [meta] & [meta.se]. [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/3404097) [ask] [Help] Reflect research in posts.

Comment: Standard SQL comma means cross join with lower precedence than keyword JOINs. That's all.

Comment: @philipxy Thanks. I did research this issue before posting and could not find any posts that were able to explain this. It appears from the suggestions above that the comma after the ON phrase of the last LEFT is being missed. If that comma was not there then I would agree this is a mix of explicit LEFT joins with implicit INNER joins. But that comma throws me. It's not clear if the tables after that comma should be treated as INNER or LEFT joins.

Comment: If it helps, this is the syntax in question here:
SELECT a.id
FROM tableA a LEFT JOIN tableB b ON a.id = b.a_id, tableC, tableD

Comment: I think if you replace commas with CROSS JOIN it should give you same result. At least that's how i'd parse the query

Comment: There's another syntax which is even more rare, i'd call it double join: 
select *
from #project p
left join #community c
left join #lookupvalue lv
 ON lv.record_id = c.record_id
 ON c.record_id = p.record_id

Comment: Please clarify via edits, not comments. Please delete & flag obsolete comments. PS I don't understand "is being missed". Please edit your post to say whatever you mean clearly. But: I just said, as does the linked Q&A I gave, `x join y on p , z` is `(x join y on p) , z` is `(x join y on p) cross join z`. Which is `x join y on p cross join z`. PS If something "appears", give an appropriate [mre]. PS There is no "implicit INNER join", "implicit join" is comma is a cross join. Although some DBMSs like MySQL let you write JOIN with no ON which is taken as ON TRUE ie CROSS JOIN.

Comment: This is a syntax question rather than a data issue, so it doesn't really take a MRE to answer it. In this case it was pretty simple task to reformat the supplied query as an answer by example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The comma is an obsolete join syntax equivalent to a `CROSS JOIN`. When coupled with an appropriate limiting condition in the `WHERE` clause, it is effectively an `INNER JOIN`.

The following is your query converted to use ANSI join syntax, where I have moved the appropriate limiting conditions to `ON` clauses.

```
SELECT *
FROM project p
LEFT OUTER JOIN last_update lu ON lu.parent_table = 'project' AND lu.parent_id = p.record_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN project_final_report pfr ON pfr.project_id = p.record_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN logininfo logr ON logr.login_id = p.project_review_by
LEFT OUTER JOIN logininfo logfr ON logfr.login_id = pfr.last_updated_by
JOIN community c ON c.record_id = p.community_id
JOIN lookupvalue lv ON lv.record_id = c.epa_region_id
JOIN lookupvalue d ON d.record_id = p.district_id
JOIN lookupvalue r ON r.record_id = p.res_id
JOIN lookupvalue su ON su.record_id = p.servunit_id
JOIN lookupvalue a ON a.record_id = p.area_id
JOIN lookupvalue pc ON pc.record_id = p.project_category_id
JOIN lookupvalue pm ON pm.record_id = p.procurement_method_id
JOIN area_settings ON area_settings.area_id = p.area_id
WHERE p.record_id = 12345
AND p.data_system_type = 'P'
```

The (subjectively less readable) direct translation of your query is:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    project p
    LEFT OUTER JOIN last_update lu ON lu.parent_table = 'project' AND lu.parent_id = p.record_id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN project_final_report pfr ON pfr.project_id = p.record_id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN logininfo logr ON logr.login_id = p.project_review_by
    LEFT OUTER JOIN logininfo logfr ON logfr.login_id = pfr.last_updated_by
)
CROSS JOIN community c
CROSS JOIN lookupvalue lv
CROSS JOIN lookupvalue d
CROSS JOIN lookupvalue r
CROSS JOIN lookupvalue su
CROSS JOIN lookupvalue a
CROSS JOIN lookupvalue pc
CROSS JOIN lookupvalue pm
CROSS JOIN area_settings
WHERE p.record_id = 12345
AND p.data_system_type = 'P'
AND p.community_id = c.record_id
AND c.epa_region_id = lv.record_id
AND d.record_id = p.district_id
AND r.record_id = p.res_id
AND su.record_id = p.servunit_id
AND a.record_id = p.area_id
AND pc.record_id = p.project_category_id
AND pm.record_id = p.procurement_method_id
AND area_settings.area_id = p.area_id
```

(Note that the parenthesis above define join groupings and not a subselect.)

Comment: The parentheses are not needed. Just like within each chain of similar joins.

Comment: Thanks https://stackoverflow.com/users/12637193/t-n, much appreciated!

Comment: @philipxy - Agree. I only included them to emphasize precedence (just as `A * B * C + E + F` might be written `(A * B * C) + E + F`), not because they were required. I eliminated them from the final form.