# Adding a table that value isn't in - Oracle SQL Developer

Tags: sql, join, left-join, oracle-sqldeveloper, sql-null

I am trying to pull store data for locations in the US and around the world.

```
select
    s.store,
    s.store_name,
    s.store_city,
    s.state,
    st.description as "STATE_DESC",
    s.country_id,
    c.country_desc
from
    store s,
    country c
left join state st on st.state = s.state
where c.country_id = s.country_id
and s.store in ('123456', '654321')
```

I get:

```
ORA-00904: "S"."STATE": invalid identifier
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 13 Column: 34
```

If I join the state table regularly, it only pulls up locations in the US and does not show NULL values in the state or state description column.

How do I join the state table?

`store` columns:
STORE
STORE_NAME
STORE_CITY
STATE
COUNTRY_ID

`state` columns:
STATE
DESCRIPTION

I want:

| STORE | STORE_NAME | STORE_CITY | STATE | STATE_DESC | COUNTRY_ID | COUNTRY_DESC |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123456 | DALLAS STORE | DALLAS | TX | Texas | US | United States |
| 654321 | GERMANY STORE | BERLIN | null | null | DE | Germany |

I ended up doing a `VLOOKUP` to add the state description in Excel.

Comment: Don combine comma separated tables with joins use only joins, you can also try the format button for code instaed of using html tags

Comment: Explicit JOINs are evaluated _before_ comma separated, implicit ones. This means the ON clause has no access to s columns.

Comment: Tip of today: Always use modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax everywhere. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read and maintain, and easier to convert to outer join if needed!

Comment: Please read the editor help re how to format using 'markdown' without html, including code blocks & inline code. https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help Please avoid social & meta commentary in posts. Please clarify via edits, not comments; delete & flag obsolete comments.Debug questions require a [mre]. [ask] [Help] ) [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/3404097)

Comment: [Mixing implicit and explicit JOINs](https://stackoverflow.com/q/761545/3404097)

Comment: Answers do not belong in question posts, post an answer in an answer post. [answer]

Answer (score 0):

Instead of joining tables by using the implicit comma seperated way, Aly S joined all the tables with the "modern, explicit JOIN syntax".

```
select
 s.store,
 s.store_name,
 s.store_city,
 s.state,
 st.description as "STATE_DESC",
 s.country_id,
 c.country_desc
from store s
left join state st
 on s.state = st.state
join country c
 on s.country_id = c.country_id
where s.store in ('123456', '654321')
```