# SQL left join - incorrect query to fix

Tags: sqlite, left-join

I was given the exercise attached but the result it gave was wrong. (I don't know what the correct result is.) There is something wrong after ON clause, but I don't know what.

Exercise and the database columns: (https://i.stack.imgur.com/xy3uJ.png)

My incorrect query:

```
SELECT artists.name, title, unitprice
FROM albums, artists
left join tracks 
ON artists.artistid = albums.artistid and albums.albumid = tracks.albumid
where artists.name = "Audioslave";
```

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Mixing implicit and explicit JOINs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/761545/mixing-implicit-and-explicit-joins)

Comment: Clearly when pinned down this is extremely likely a faq. Please before considering posting: Pin down code issues via [mre]. Read manuals/references & google error messages & many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular names/strings/numbers, 'site:stackoverflow.com' & tags; read many answers. SO/SE search is poor & literal & unusual, read the help. Google re googling/searching, including Q&A at [meta] & [meta.se]. [research effort is expected?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/3404097) [ask] [Help] Reflect research in posts.

Comment: Debug questions require a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code including initialization; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. For SQL include DDL & tabular initialization code. For debug that includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. [ask] [Help] When you get a result you don't expect, pause your overall goal, chop to the 1st subexpression with unexpected result & say what you expected & why, justified by documentation. (Debugging fundamental.)

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you want:-

```
SELECT title,tracks.name, unitprice 
FROM albums 
LEFT JOIN artists ON artists.artistid = albums.artistid 
LEFT JOIN tracks ON albums.albumid = tracks.albumid 
WHERE artists.name = 'Audioslave';
```

- noting that tracks.name isn't asked for but does help to clarify.
- The artist name, due to the WHERE clause will all be the same.
- The Albums table is the core table, to which you can join the Artists table and also the Tracks table
- p.s. note the use of single quotes around the literal value (Audioslave) (double quotes will result in a column not found error)

The results include (not all 40 rows):-

[image]

....

An alternative, if the question is asking for the sum of the unit prices per album, could be:-

```
SELECT title, sum(unitprice) FROM albums LEFT JOIN artists ON artists.artistid = albums.artistid LEFT JOIN tracks ON albums.albumid = tracks.albumid WHERE artists.name = 'Audioslave' GROUP BY albums.albumid;
```

- `sum` is an aggregate function, that works on a group.

  - by default all rows extracted are a group. However the use of the GROUP BY clause creates a GROUP per album (as each albumid will be unique).
  - It would be confusing to include the track's name as it would be one of the names (arbitrary based upon the order as cetermined by the query optimizer).

The result of the second query would be:-

[image]

- you could use `sum(unitprice) AS unitprice` to better name the output column.

You could go overboard and do something like:-

```
SELECT 
    title, 
    sum(unitprice) AS albumprice, 
    count(unitprice) AS Tracks, 
    avg(unitprice) AS AVGPrice, 
    group_concat(tracks.name,', ') AS tracklist  
FROM albums 
LEFT JOIN artists ON artists.artistid = albums.artistid 
LEFT JOIN tracks ON albums.albumid = tracks.albumid 
WHERE artists.name = 'Audioslave' 
GROUP BY albums.albumid
;
```

- i.e. use even more aggregate functions (count, avg and group_concat)

In which case the result would be (note not all tracks shown):-

[image]

- note that if a column name is unqiue then you don't need to use the table name followed by `.` before the column name.

  - the tracks table and the artists table both have a column call name, so the ambiguity most be resolved using the table name followed by `.`, whilst unitprice is unique to the tracks table.

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097)