# Mixing explicit and implicit joins fails with "There is an entry for table ... but it cannot be referenced from this part of the query"

Tags: sql, postgresql

```
SELECT
      i.*, 
      r.name AS roomname, 
      c.name AS cat, 
      p.key AS imgkey, 
      p.extension AS imgext
   FROM 
      items i, 
      rooms r, 
      categories c 
         LEFT JOIN photos p 
            ON p.referencekey = i.key 
   WHERE 
          i.room = r.key 
      AND r.key = 663308 
      AND i.sitekey = 32201 
      AND c.key = i.categorykey
```

The above query when executed returns following error.

> ERROR:  invalid reference to FROM-clause entry for table "i"
>
> LINE 1: ...tegory c LEFT JOIN photos p ON p.referencekey = i.key WHER...
>
> HINT:  There is an entry for table "i", but it cannot be referenced from this part of the query.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Not disagreeing, but context/reasons for "never ever mix... " would be helpful here

Comment: @kevlarr: see this question for at least one reason

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name The answers here indicate that mixing joins is merely a little messy rather than being something one should not do for one reason or another. I agree with you about not mixing them, but only really because of clarity - are there more objective reasons for not mixing? (Asking because I would like knowing/learning.)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name which question? there's no link

Comment: @user2297550 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6347897/mixing-explicit-and-implicit-joins-fails-with-there-is-an-entry-for-table-b i.e. *this* question

Comment: @kevlarr clarity is *really* important

Comment: @Caleth Absolutely agree that clarity is important. I was only suggesting that "Never ever mix implicit and explicit joins" is a great rule of thumb but it doesn't help people learn, as it - and the other answers - don't go into good detail on *why* they shouldn't ever be mixed. At least, there aren't objective reasons that non-experts like me would read as "A-ha, *that's* why I should never use implicit!"... I personally don't use implicit because I *like* the clarity of using `JOIN ... ON ...` but I don't know if there are performance benefits, etc.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Inner join & outer join; is the order of tables in from important?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/187146/inner-join-outer-join-is-the-order-of-tables-in-from-important)

Answer (score 60, accepted):

The SQL spec states that explicit joins are performed before implicit joins. This is an implicit join:

```
FROM table1 t1, table2 t2 WHERE t1.id=t2.t1id
```

This is an explicit join:

```
FROM table1 t1 JOIN table2 t2 ON (t1.id=t2.t1id)
```

This code bit:

```
categories c 
     LEFT JOIN photos p 
        ON p.referencekey = i.key
```

is an explicit join and is run first.  Note that at this point the table aliased as i hasn't been looked at yet, so it can't be joined yet.  Note that MySQL fixed this behaviour in 5.2 I believe, and this query will no longer work there either.

Comment: Thanks for explanation. In my case there was enough to change table names order in cartesian product :)

Answer (score 35):

Move your `JOIN` statement next to the table you are joining on:

```
SELECT
      i.*, 
      r.name AS roomname, 
      c.name AS cat, 
      p.key AS imgkey, 
      p.extension AS imgext
   FROM 
      items i
         LEFT JOIN photos p 
            ON p.referencekey = i.key, 
      rooms r, 
      categories c 
   WHERE 
          i.room = r.key 
      AND r.key = 663308 
      AND i.sitekey = 32201 
      AND c.key = i.categorykey
```

The long explanation:

A `JOIN` is part of an expression that results in a source table, used in the `FROM` clause as a [*from_item*](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-select.html).  Your `FROM` clause has 3 *from_item* source tables:

- `items`
- `rooms`
- `categories` joined to `photos`

The error is in the `ON` *join_condition* of your `categories` joined to `photos` *from_item*.  You are referencing a table, `items`, that does not exist in the *from_item*.  The solution is to move the `photos` join into the `items` *from_item*, so that you have the following *from_item* source tables:

- `items` joined to `photos`
- `rooms`
- `categories`

Sadly, I can't find an example in the documentation that makes clear this relationship between a table in the `FROM` clause and a `JOIN`.  The [`SELECT` Synopsis](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-select.html) shows this syntax and is the best source in the documentation to find this distinction.  Notice that a `JOIN` is not a sibling clause to `FROM`, but actually part of a *from_item* within the `FROM` clause.  Thus, if your `FROM` clause consists of a list of tables, each table in that list can have its own joins.  Then it becomes more intuitive that each table involved in a join must be included in a single *from_item*.

Comment: Great explanation. While the accepted answer provides an arguably more sensible solution, this one gets to the heart of the issue (that JOIN clauses are associated with the table immediately preceding it in the FROM clause).

Comment: Thanks.  I always prefer to understand a problem, rather than merely solve it.  That's why I added an answer to this old forgotten question.

Comment: From your own link: "The FROM clause specifies one or more source tables for the SELECT. If multiple sources are specified, the result is the Cartesian product (cross join) of all the sources." It later confirms: "In any case JOIN binds more tightly than the commas separating FROM-list items."

Comment: This is one of the clearest descriptions of joins that I have read. "Notice that a JOIN is not a sibling clause to FROM, but actually part of a from_item within the FROM clause. Thus, if your FROM clause consists of a list of tables, each table in that list can have its own joins."

Answer (score 16):

Since your Items.Room = the Rooms.Key, I would just have that as the where..

```
SELECT
      i.*, 
      r.name AS roomname, 
      c.name AS cat, 
      p.key AS imgkey, 
      p.extension AS imgext
   FROM 
      items i
         LEFT JOIN photos p 
            ON p.referencekey = i.key 
         JOIN rooms r
            on i.room = r.key
         JOIN categories c 
            on i.categorykey = c.key
   WHERE 
          i.sitekey = 32201 
      AND i.room = 663308
```