# Cannot replicate PostgresQL query with joins in knex.js

Tags: javascript, postgresql, knex.js

I'm working with the following tables/schemas:

`Users` have `id` as primary, also `email`, `username`, etc.

`Studies` have a `users` property: an array of integers (which are all user ids).

**Question**: What I would like to do is find the id/username/email of all users related to a single study.

My actual working PostgresQL query is as follows (schema/table names shortened for brevity):

```
SELECT u.id, u.username, u.email
FROM users u
INNER JOIN studies s
  ON u.id = ANY(s.users)
WHERE s.id = 1
```

This will successfully get me a list of users who are on the study with id of 1.

However, my problem lies with converting this query using `knex.js`. I have tried the following:

```
return knex('users')
  .select('id', 'username', 'email')
  .from('users')
  .innerJoin('studies', 'users.id', '=', 'ANY(studies.users)')
  .where('studies.id', 1);
```

Yet, this returns an error:

> 42P01 There is an entry for table \\"studies\\", but it cannot be referenced from this part of the query.

I have also tried the following which all have the same error:

```
// fails
return knex('users')
  .join('studies', 'users.id', 'ANY(studies.users)')
  .select('users.id', 'users.username', 'users.email')
  .where('studies.id', 1);

// fails
return knex('users')
  .select('id', 'username', 'email')
  .from('users')
  .innerJoin('studies', function() {
     this.on('users.id', '=', 'ANY(studies.users)');
  })
  .where('studies.id', 1);
```

I have seen [this question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6347897/mixing-explicit-and-implicit-joins-fails-with-there-is-an-entry-for-table-b) but I don't see how I'm mixing explicit and implicit joins. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

---

**Update**

I've resorted to using `knex.raw` for now as I don't understand what the issue is with chaining the other methods. I don't find it nearly as reusable as I'd prefer, but it works none-the-less. Here's what I ended up going with:

```
async function getAllByStudy(studyId) {
  try {
    const results = await knex.raw(`
      SELECT u.id, u.username, u.email
      FROM users u
      INNER JOIN studies s
        ON u.id = ANY(s.users)
      WHERE s.id = ${studyId}
    `);
    return results.rows;
  } catch (err) {
    return new Error(err);
  }
}
```

The `async/await` features allowed for some nice structure since `knex.raw` is asynchronous. I'm settling with it for now but if anyone has a better way to do it please let me know!

Comment: Can't avoid to use ANY?

Comment: I've also tried using array notation and checking against `ARRAY['studies.users']::integer[]` but that fails just the same.

Comment: which data type is studies.users? array of integers?

Comment: That's correct.

Comment: You could try by using [onIN](http://knexjs.org/#Builder-onIn) and [UNNEST](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/90462/110455) (Note: I'm not good on knex)

Answer (score 1):

you didn't mention the relation betweens `users` and `studies` table (OneToOne or OneToMany).

And it will be easy if you start your query with `studies` table as

```
knex('studies')
.leftJoin('users', 'users.id', 'users.user_id')
.where('studies.id', YOUR_QUERY_ID)
.columns([
  'users.id',
  'users.username',
  'users.email'
])
.then((results) => {
  console.log(results) // array
})
```

**Edit 1**
Database Table Joins-
[image]

Comment: Could you explain the `leftJoin`? I don't understand where `users.users_id` comes from. The relationship between users and studies is ManyToMany: multiple users can be in a study, and users can belong to as many studies as necessary. I very much appreciate your answer, as well - at least it is not throwing any errors! Just returns with an empty object.

Comment: I edited my answer with little explaining table joins. And it should return array if your studies tables has proper data.

Comment: Thanks for the diagram! I'm continuing to get the same errors, however.