# How to successfully use JOIN queries?

Tags: sql, postgresql, join

These are my schemas:

```
CREATE TABLE CUSTOMER
(
    customerID numeric,
    name text,
    email varchar(320),
    cell varchar,
    address varchar,
    flag text NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(customerID)
);

CREATE TABLE REFERRALS
(
    customerID numeric NOT NULL,
    name text NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(customerID, name)
);

CREATE TABLE RENTAL
(
    customerID numeric NOT NULL,
    model numeric NOT NULL,
    borrowDate timestamp NOT NULL,
    dueDate date NOT NULL,
    charge money NOT NULL,
    returnDate timestamp NULL,
    addFees money NULL,
    notes text NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(customerID, model, borrowDate)
);

CREATE TABLE SCOOTER
(
    model bigserial NOT NULL,
    manufacturer text NOT NULL,
    country text NOT NULL,
    range numeric NOT NULL,
    weight numeric NOT NULL,
    topspeed numeric NOT NULL,
    condition text NOT NULL,
    availability text NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(model)
);
```

For the first query, I want to show the model and manufacturer columns from `SCOOTER`, the name column from `CUSTOMER`, and the dueDate column from `RENTAL`, but only for in rows where `SCOOTER.model = RENTAL.model` and where `RENTAL.returnDate is NULL`. And finally, in descending order by dueDate.

This is the query I wrote:

```
SELECT 
    s.model, s.manufacturer, c.name, r.duedate 
FROM 
    SCOOTER AS s, CUSTOMER AS c 
INNER JOIN 
    RENTAL AS r ON r.model = s.model AND r.returnDate IS NULL 
ORDER BY 
    r.duedate DESC;
```

I get this error however:

> HINT: There is an entry for table "s", but it cannot be referenced from this part of the query.
>   STATEMENT:  SELECT s.model, s.manufacturer, c.name, r.duedate FROM SCOOTER AS s, CUSTOMER AS c 
>           INNER JOIN RENTAL AS r ON r.model = s.model AND r.returnDate IS NULL ORDER BY r.duedate desc;
>
> ERROR:  invalid reference to FROM-clause entry for table "s"
>   LINE 2: INNER JOIN RENTAL AS r ON r.model = s.model AND r.returnDate...
>                                                  ^
>   HINT:  There is an entry for table "s", but it cannot be referenced from this part of the query.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mixing explicit and implicit joins fails with "There is an entry for table ... but it cannot be referenced from this part of the query"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6347897/mixing-explicit-and-implicit-joins-fails-with-there-is-an-entry-for-table-b)

Comment: Comma does a cross join but is lower precedence than explicit keyword JOINs. So the JOIN ON is done first. So s is not in scope in the ON. Using CROSS JOIN instead of comma would be OK. But what did you learn from reading all answers of many hits googling your error message with & without your particular strings? I did the latter & the first hit answered your question. PS Don't mix comma with JOINs. PS This is a faq but hard to find without the error message. But make sure you've read the manual about everthing you use.

Comment: This is a faq. Please always google many clear, concise & specific versions/phrasings of your question/problem/goal with & without your particular strings/names & 'site:stackoverflow.com' & tags & read many answers. Add relevant keywords you discover to your searches. If you don't find an answer then post, using 1 variant search as title & keywords for tags. See the downvote arrow mouseover text. When you do have a non-duplicate code question to post please read & act on [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

Well, I think you should study a little bit better SQL. You only connect table RENTAL and SCOOTER, but you left out the connection with CUSTOMER.

Your code should probably look more like

```
SELECT SCOOTER.model, SCOOTER.manufacturer, CUSTOMER.name, RENTAL.duedate
FROM SCOOTER
INNER JOIN RENTAL ON RENTAL.model = SCOOTER.model
INNER JOIN CUSTOMER ON RENTAL.customerID = CUSTOMER.customerID
WHERE RENTAL.returnDate IS NULL ORDER BY RENTAL.duedate desc;
```

Hope it helps!

Cheers

Comment: There is no problem with putting any condition in either ON or WHERE here.

Comment: @philipxy thank you for pointing that out, I'll correct my answer!

Answer (score 0):

You're mixing join styles there, something to be avoided. Joins look like this:

```
SELECT * FROM 
a 
INNER JOIN b ON a.column = b.column
INNER JOIN c ON a.column = c.column ...
```

Every row from a is connected to every row from b, where the ON clause is true. Then every row from a-b is connected to C again where the ON clause is true. This causes the data to grow sideways as more data from more tables is joined on. Tables can even be joined to themselves.

It's hard (and off topic for SO) to go into depth about every aspect of JOINs so some background reading will probably be essential

Comment: See my comment on the question. It's just a matter of precedence.