# ERROR: invalid reference to FROM-clause

Tags: postgresql, join

I have the following SQL (PostgreSQL) query:

```
SELECT ff.*, fp.*
FROM fibra ff, fibra fp

JOIN cables cp ON fp.cable_id = cp.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN terceiro  ced_pai ON ced_pai.id = cp.cedente_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN terceiro tp ON tp.id = fp.terceiro_id

JOIN cables cf ON ff.cable_id = cf.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN terceiro ced_f ON ced_f.id = cf.cedente_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN terceiro tf ON tf.id = ff.terceiro_id

where ff.fibra_pai_id = fp.id 
AND ff.cable_id IN (8,9,10) 
AND fp.cable_id IN (8,9,10)
```

But it's giving me this error:

```
ERROR:  invalid reference to FROM-clause entry for table "ff"
LINE 8:  JOIN cables cf ON ff.cable_id = cf.id
           ^
HINT:  There is an entry for table "ff", but it cannot be referenced from this part of the query.

********** Error **********

ERROR: invalid reference to FROM-clause entry for table "ff"
SQL state: 42P01
Hint: There is an entry for table "ff", but it cannot be referenced from this part of the query.
Character: 261
```

Does anyone know what AM I doing wrong ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's wrong with this query?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6347897/whats-wrong-with-this-query)

Comment: Also this question is the same: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/187146/inner-join-outer-join-is-the-order-of-tables-in-from-important

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Inner join & outer join; is the order of tables in from important?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/187146/inner-join-outer-join-is-the-order-of-tables-in-from-important)

Answer (score 53, accepted):

You are mixing implicit and explicit JOINs. That's generally confusing to read, and leads to unexpected order-of-evaluation problems, as you've just discovered.

You should consistently use `JOIN ... ON` syntax everywhere; avoid the legacy `FROM table1, table2`. If you correct your query to use an explicit JOIN instead of `FROM fibra ff, fibra fp`, eg `FROM fibra ff INNER JOIN fibra fp ON (ff.fibra_pai_id = fp.id)` and omit `ff.fibra_pai_id = fp.id` from the `WHERE` clause, you should get the expected result.

See this question that A.H. linked to:

[Mixing explicit and implicit joins fails with "There is an entry for table ... but it cannot be referenced from this part of the query"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6347897/whats-wrong-with-this-query)

Comment: Thanks. Have read this and other posts. I just don't know if yesterday I was too tired or the explanations were not really clear, but I couldn't get the point reading those. But your explanation today made me understand. Thanks.

Comment: **legacy** `FROM`? Really? It is used to compute the _Cartesian Product_ and you need it even to use `INNER JOIN`, don't you? http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/sql-select.html#SQL-FROM

Comment: @AlexisWilke `FROM` is of course not "legacy" in any sense. The non-ansi join syntax `FROM table1, table2 WHERE tablea.id = tableb.id` is generally considered to be though, with ANSI inner joins favoured instead. If you want an unfiltered cartesian product you can use `tablea CROSS JOIN tableb`, making your intentions explicit.

Answer (score 2):

Convert all the joins in your query to be explicit to avoid the issue you're having--don't leave some implicit and others explicit.

This should work:

```
SELECT ff.*, fp.*
  FROM fibra ff

  JOIN fibra fp ON ff.fibra_pai_id = fp.id 

  JOIN cables cp ON fp.cable_id = cp.id
  LEFT OUTER JOIN terceiro  ced_pai ON ced_pai.id = cp.cedente_id
  LEFT OUTER JOIN terceiro tp ON tp.id = fp.terceiro_id

  JOIN cables cf ON ff.cable_id = cf.id
  LEFT OUTER JOIN terceiro ced_f ON ced_f.id = cf.cedente_id
  LEFT OUTER JOIN terceiro tf ON tf.id = ff.terceiro_id

WHERE
 ff.cable_id IN (8,9,10) 
 AND fp.cable_id IN (8,9,10)
```

Comment: In this case a note explaining what you changed in the query may help the poster understand *what* was wrong and *why*, not just copy new query text to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the problem was that I forgot I had assigned my tables to a particular schema and needed to reference those e.g:

```
select r.*
from my_schema.resources r
```