# Getting from clause entry error when trying to join table

Tags: sql, postgresql

Here is my query, but I'm getting this error

```
ValueError: "invalid reference to FROM-clause entry for table "p"
LINE 5:             JOIN res_country as rc on (rc.id = p.country_id)...
                                                       ^
HINT:  There is an entry for table "p", but it cannot be referenced from this part of the query.



SELECT DISTINCT p.id AS id, rc.code as country_code, p.name AS name, 
(select up.name from res_partner up where up.id = (select u.partner_id from res_users u where u.id = p.user_id)) as user, p.ref as ref
           
            FROM res_partner p, account_move_line l, account_account
            JOIN res_country as rc on (rc.id = p.country_id) 
            WHERE l.account_id = account_account.id
                AND l.partner_id = p.id
                AND account_account.company_id = 1
                
                AND account_account.reconcile = True
                
            ORDER BY p.name
```

what is wrong with my query?

Comment: Explicit JOIN's are evaluated before comma separated ones. I.e. p is not "visible" in the ON clause,

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ERROR: invalid reference to FROM-clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13297491/error-invalid-reference-to-from-clause)

Answer (score 2):

You are mixing the outdated implicit joins and the "modern" explicit JOIN operator. This is always a bad idea and the main reason for your error as the evaluation rules are different for both.

If you only use the explicit JOIN operator you will also immediate see that you are missing a join condition between for the `account_account` table

```
...
FROM res_partner p
  JOIN account_account ON ?????
  JOIN account_move_line l 
    ON l.account_id = account_account.id
   AND l.partner_id = p.id
  JOIN res_country as rc on (rc.id = p.country_id) 
WHERE account_account.company_id = 1
  AND account_account.reconcile = True
```