# entry cannot be referenced in this part of the query (subquery) Error

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm getting the following error on my query:

```
here is an entry for table "table1", but it cannot be referenced from this part of the query.
```

This is my query:

```
SELECT id 
FROM property_import_image_results table1
  LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT created_at 
    FROM property_import_image_results
    WHERE external_url = table1.external_url
    ORDER BY created_at DESC NULLS LAST 
    LIMIT 1
  ) as table2 ON (pimr.created_at = table2.created_at)
WHERE table2.created_at is NULL
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mixing explicit and implicit joins fails with "There is an entry for table ... but it cannot be referenced from this part of the query"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6347897/mixing-explicit-and-implicit-joins-fails-with-there-is-an-entry-for-table-b)

Comment: See also: [ERROR: invalid reference to FROM-clause](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13297491/error-invalid-reference-to-from-clause) or [Inner join & outer join; is the order of tables in from important?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/187146/inner-join-outer-join-is-the-order-of-tables-in-from-important)

Comment: What is the **real** problem you are trying to solve here? It _seems_ to me, this could be done in a more efficient way, but I'm unsure what your actual goal is.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need a lateral join to be able to reference the outer table in the sub-select for the join.

You are also referencing an alias `pimr` in the join condition, which isn't available anywhere in the query. So you need to change that to `table1` in the join condition.

You should also given the table in the *inner* query an alias to avoid confusion:

```
SELECT id 
FROM property_import_image_results table1
  LEFT JOIN LATERAL (
    SELECT p2.created_at 
    FROM property_import_image_results p2
    WHERE p2.external_url = table1.external_url
    ORDER BY p2.created_at DESC NULLS LAST 
    LIMIT 1
  ) as table2 ON (table1.created_at = table2.created_at)
WHERE table2.created_at is NULL
```

**Edit**

This kind of query can also be solved using window functions:

```
select id
from (
  select id,  
         max(created_at) over (partition by external_url) as max_created
  FROM property_import_image_results
) t
where created_at <> max_created;
```

This *might* be faster than aggregating and joining as you do. But it's hard to tell. The lateral joins are quite efficient as well. It has the advantage that you can add any column you like to the result because no grouping is required.

Comment: This worked @a_horse_with_no_name. Thanks. But regarding your question up there, maybe this could be done in a more efficient way. What Im trying to achieve is group by external_url the entries on property_import_image_results, and discard the most recent one on each group. Something like the opposite of: 
SELECT id FROM property_import_image_results GROUP BY external_url ORDERED BY created_at DESC LIMIT 1

Comment: That might work, but I've found max() to be really not efficient (as discussed here: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/51895/efficient-query-to-get-greatest-value-per-group-from-big-table).

Comment: @ntonnelier: as I said: it _might_ (or might not) be more efficient. You need to test it with your data.